# O que é syntax sugar e como ela funciona?

Tags: java, sintaxe, syntactic-sugar

Tenho visto em alguns blogs o uso do desse termo e gostaria de saber:

1) O real significado dessa expressão e;

2) Como funciona uma **syntax** sugar como a do exemplo abaixo na linguagem [java](/questions/tagged/java)?

```
for (Foo foo : listFoo) {
    //CÓDIGO AQUI
}
```

Comment: Você quer saber o que significa "syntax sugar" ou quer saber como funciona esse exemplo de sugar? Se for os dois, você está fazendo duas perguntas completamente não relacionadas e deveriam ser separadas.

Comment: As duas coisas. Vou enumerá-las para demonstrar melhor a minha necessidade.

Comment: Então separe em duas perguntas diferentes. Syntax sugar é uma coisa, como o for funciona não tem nenhuma relação e não pode estar na mesma pergunta.

Comment: Perdão, @bigown, mas acredito que uma definição associada a um exemplo venha facilitar a minha compreensão sobre o termo.

Comment: Mas ainda assim são coisas separadas, não sei porque ter as duas informações em páginas diferentes possa complicar a compreensão. Já a organização do site fica prejudicada com duas perguntas não relacionadas no mesmo lugar.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Literalmente, *syntax sugar* é um tipo de construção feita para "adocicar" o código, ou seja, fazer algo de maneira mais simples.

Considerando o seu exemplo do *for-each*. Antes do Java 5, da nova construção "adocicada" e da introdução de genéricos na linguagem, eis um código equivalente:

```
for (Iterator i = listFoo.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Foo foo = (Foo) i.next();    
    // CÓDIGO AQUI
}
```

A versão com o *for-each* é com certeza mais simples e menos suscetível a falhas.

---

**Fontes:**

- [SOE: Which is more efficient, a for-each loop, or an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113216/which-is-more-efficient-a-for-each-loop-or-an-iterator)
- [Java Language Specification: 14.14.2. The enhanced for statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)

Answer (score 10):

> Em ciência da computação, açúcar sintático é a sintaxe dentro de uma linguagem de programação que foi concebido para tornar as coisas mais fáceis para ler ou expressar. Isso torna a linguagem "mais doce" para uso humano: as coisas podem ser expressas de forma mais clara, de forma mais concisa, ou em um estilo alternativo que alguns podem preferir.

Traduzido de: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar

Este `for` itera sobre todos os elementos de `listFoo`, colocando a cada iteração o elemento corrente dentro da variável `foo`.

Comment: Mas é que nem café: tem gente que prefere sem açúcar, e tem gente que usa mais açúcar que café.

Comment: Aí vai da filosofia de cada um. Por um lado, fazer uma coisa de várias maneiras pode complicar. Por outro, melhora o poder de expressão da linguagem.