# Como funciona um construtor vazio?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, construtor

**Definição:** Criando um construtor vazio os atributos caso não sejam *setados* ficarão com o valor padrão do **tipo**, exemplo: `int` valor padrão é zero.

**Contexto:** Uso uma estrutura que retorna entidades do banco de dados e quando o objeto não é encontrado ele retorna **nulo**, então usei esse *coringa* do construtor, para quando isso acontecer instanciar o objeto com o construtor vazio, tive que usar polimorfismo no construtor pois já havia um construtor, exemplo: `var pessoa = PessoaController.Obter(id) ?? new Pessoa();`

**Dúvida:** Como funciona isso? Como o programa faz essa associação que construtor vazio quer dizer *setar* todos os atributos para valores padrão? É usado quando classes possuem atributos que são outras classes além desse caso existem outros usos dessa técnica? Existe outra forma de implementar isso sem utilizar um construtor?

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public Pessoa() { }
    public Pessoa(string nome, DateTime dtNasc, int cpf)
    {
        Nome = nome;
        DataNascimento = dtNasc;
        CPF = cpf;
    }
}

public class Faculdade
{
    public Pessoa Mantenedor { get; set; }
    public List<Aluno> Alunos { get; set;}
    public List<Disciplina> Disciplinas { get; set; }

    public Faculdade()
    {
        Mantenedor = new Pessoa();
        Alunos = new List<Aluno>();
        Disciplinas = new List<Disciplina>();
    }
}

public class Aluno
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int RM { get; set; }
    public bool Sexo { get; set; }          
    public Aluno() { }
}

public class Disciplina
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Disciplina() { }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Faculdade USP = new Faculdade();
    Console.Write(USP.Mantenedor.Nome); // Retorna vazio
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: É perfeitamente válido usar o operador de coalescência dessa forma. Geralmente eu uso o mesmo código para as ações de Create e Update, de forma que ao se consultar o DB pelo ID do objeto, o retorno for nulo, então significa que um novo está sendo criado... daí posso ter um objeto com certeza dessa forma: `var entity = db.Entidade.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id) ?? new Entidade();`. Depois dessa linha é certo que `entity` não é nulo.

Comment: Uma coisa legal que tem no C# 6 é que as propriedades agora podem ter um inicializador: `public Pessoa Mantenedor { get; set; } = new Pessoa();` E com o novo recurso Primary Constructor, fica mais fácil ainda inicializar toda uma classe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Todo objeto é inicialmente construído com valores padrão para todos os seus membros. Isso é uma referência nula para todos os membros cujos tipos forem por referência, e o valor padrão do tipo para todos os demais membros. Nesse caso, o valor padrão depende da implementação do tipo. Em geral, é equivalente a zero para tipos numéricos (`short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `uint` etc.), a menor data utilizável para `DateTime`, um intervalo de tempo zero para `TimeSPan` etc.

Se você declara um construtor no qual os membros são modificados, a modificação ocorre **após** a construção do objeto. Pense nisso: você necessariamente precisa de um objeto já construído para poder operar sobre ele. Acredito que a causa da confusão seja justamente o nome "construtor", já que ele irá agir sobre um objeto já construído.

O processo na verdade é o seguinte:

objeto não existe -> **requisição ao construtor** -> **alocação** -> **construção** -> **seu construtor é executado no objeto recém-construído** -> controle volta para o seu programa

Explicando de outra forma: quando o programa se depara com uma instrução do tipo:

```
var f = new Foo(bar);
```

- O programa cria um objeto do tipo `Foo`;
- Em seguida executa o construtor utilizado (no caso, o que recebe a variável `bar`) sobre o objeto que acaba de ser criado;
- Finalmente, a aplicação faz com que a referência `f` "aponte" para o objeto criado.

Perceba que não necessariamente um construtor precisa alterar os membros do objeto sobre o qual opera. Ele pode disparar um evento, realizar operações sobre outros objetos etc.

Declarar um construtor vazio em geral não tem significado algum, a menos que você utilize um modificador de visibilidade (i.e.: `private` ou  `internal`) para controlar os contextos nos quais seu objeto pode ser criado.

Comment: A ordem de inicialização que mencionou só pode ser observada dentro do fluxo da própria thread. Quando há várias threads, isso já não é mais verdade pois a [CLR pode reordenar escritas e leituras como se o construtor não tivesse limites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964731/the-need-for-volatile-modifier-in-double-checked-locking-in-net/12945510#12945510).

Comment: @MiguelAngelo eu não sabia disso. Vivendo e aprendendo, vlw :D

Answer (score 3):

Quando nenhum construtor é especificado em uma classe, o C# automaticamente irá compilar um construtor sem parâmetros público, que vai deixar os campos todos com os valores padrão de cada tipo. Os valores padrão para structs pode variar de tipo para tipo, e de classes é sempre nulo. Os valores padrões sempre são os valores correspondentes à memória zerada, ou seja, preenchida com bits 0.

### Para inicializar a nova instância

Você pode codificar um construtor sem parâmetros manualmente, de forma a alterar o comportamento padrão do C#, o que normalmente é feito para preencher os valores dos campos com valores que fazem sentido, ou então que sejam mais apropriados para um objeto sendo instanciado. Isso pode ser feito também com inicializadores de campos, entretanto, o código compilado pelo C# é como se a inicialização fosse feita dentro do próprio construtor:

```
private int field;
private string fieldStr;
public MyClass()
{
    this.field = 10;
    this.fieldStr = "xpto";
}
```

é exatamente o mesmo que:

```
private int field = 10;
private string fieldStr;
public MyClass()
{
    this.fieldStr = "xpto";
}
```

### Para chamar outro construtor, passando parâmetros padrão

Suponha que uma classe de base `BaseClass` só possua construtores com parâmetros. Ao herdar dessa classe, você será obrigado a fornecer um construtor para a classe, pois o C# não vai gerar um automaticamente. Assim sendo, você terá de codificar um construtor, seja ele com ou sem parâmetros:

```
class MyClass : BaseClass
{
    protected MyClass2()
        : base("param") // a base só tem construtores com parâmetros
    {
    }
}
```

### Para alterar visibilidade

Outra técnica é definir um construtor padrão só para poder alterar a visibilidade do mesmo, por exemplo, torná-lo um construtor protegido:

```
class MyClass
{
    protected MyClass()
    {
    }
}
```

então só se poderá acessar o construtor assim:

```
class MyClass2 : MyClass
{
    public MyClass2()
        : base() // chamando o construtor de MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

Alguns padrões de codificação dependem de um construtor com visibilidade reduzida:

- **Singleton:** se o construtor fosse publicamente visível, ou até mesmo, pudesse ser visto por herdeiros, poderiam acabar sendo criadas múltiplas instâncias da classe.
- **Factory:** se o construtor for visível, então outros fluxos de criação que não sejam a fábrica de objetos, poderão ser tomados.

### Construção de instância, de estrutura e estática

Não confunda construtor de instância com construtor estático. Existem diferenças entre esses construtores. O construtor de instância possui muito menos garantias que o estático, além do propósito ser diferente.

Há diferenças também entre construtores de instância e de estrutura. Não é possível criar um construtor de estrutura sem parâmetros, além do construtor de estrutura ter obrigatoriamente de preencher todos os campos da estrutura.

- **construtor estático:** inicializa membros estáticos, com a garantia de que o construtor será chamado apenas uma vez (é thread-safe), antes de qualquer utilização do tipo. Para tipos genéricos, o construtor é chamado para cada tipo que for gerado usando os parâmetros genéricos. Além disso, se o construtor estático lançar uma exceção uma vez, a exceção é armazenada e relançada todas as vezes que se user o tipo novamente.
- **construtor de instância:** inicializa os membros de uma instância da classe. Não é thread-safe, além de não fornecer nenhuma garantia em especial sobre reordenação de leituras e escritas, o que pode fazer com que um [objeto recém criado em uma thread seja observado em outra thread mal-inicializado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12945510/195417).

  É necessário instanciar antes de usar qualquer campo de um objeto da classe.
- **construtor de estrutura:** deve inicializar todos os membros da estrutura, não podendo cair no caso da questão que fala sobre construtores sem parâmetros, pois o C# não permite definir tal construtor. Ao usar o construtor padrão da estrutura, é o mesmo que usar o valor defaut do tipo:

  ```
  new MinhaStruct()  <==>  default(MinhaStruct)
  ```

  Não é necessário chamar o construtor de struct antes de setar os campos, caso sejam públicos:

  ```
  TesteStruct t;
  t.valor = 10;
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Resolvi responder atrasado porque achei problemas nas outras respostas. E também porque as novidades da linguagem e meus novos conhecimentos me fizeram refletir sobre o assunto. Não vou repetir o já falado que está correto e bem explicado.

## Erros

O primeiro ponto é o [uso errado do termo atributo quando na verdade deveria ser campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Algumas respostas dizem que o construtor coloca o valor padrão do tipos nos campos e isso não é uma verdade absoluta, acontece apenas em alguns casos. Explico abaixo.

Métodos não possuem campos (ou atributos como chamaram), possuem variáveis locais, e é outro assunto, construtores não interferem com isso.

`struct` permite definir um construtor padrão, pelo menos em versões mais novas de C#.

## O que é o construtor

Para começar entender leia [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Então o construtor, no fundo, é um inicializador. O que chamamos de construtor é só uma função que atribui valores para os campos definidos no tipo.

Aí precisamos entender outro ponto. Códigos só podem ser executados quando estão dentro de funções (mesmo em sintaxe moderna que permite fora, na verdade é só um [*syntax sugar*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12964/101) que colocará o código dentro de uma durante a compilação). O problema é que a inicialização de campos nas classes são códigos a serem executados. Toda atribuição é um código a ser executado, não importa onde ele está. Então esses códigos de inicialização precisam ser movidos para uma função que fará todas as inicializações dentro dela.

Percebeu que os valores não precisam ser o padrão? Se o campo não tem um valor a ser inicializado explicitamente aí sim o compilador assumirá o valor *default* dele, mas ainda precisará inicializar.

Em C# não é possível um campo ser usado sem inicialização. No .NET é possível porque aceita outras linguagens, algumas que permitem acessar o que estiver na memória, o que chamamos de lixo de memória.

## Por baixo dos panos

Se o programador não prover um construtor padrão (sem parâmetros) o compilador cria um para você, desde que outro construtor não tenha sido criado, aí o compilador não cria um novo padrão.

Essa função inicializadora que chamamos de construtor em suas várias sobrecargas com quaisquer parâmetros, até mesmo sem, sempre atribui valor para todos os campos em qualquer circunstância (com exceção se o tipo não tiver estado (campos)). O programador pode personalizar o construtor atribuindo valores para alguns campos e fazendo outras operações, e os campos que ele não o fizer explicitamente, será feito pelo compilador, conforme os critérios já descritos.

## Novas formas

Começando em C# 10 e melhorando nas versões seguintes a linguagem deu um passo para não precisar tanto de construtores facilitando a inicialização direta nas propriedades, forçando a inicialização na construção do objeto, ou seja, se você não tiver que inicializar em certa ordem e nem fazer outros operações dependentes, o construtor não é mais necessário.

Mas como já sabemos, o construtor ainda será criado para preencher campos que não sejam obrigados a inicializar.

Pode ver mais em [O que são estruturas de Registro no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/539114/101).

## Respondendo a pergunta principal

Declarar explicitamente o construtor vazio é desnecessário pelo que constatamos aqui, até porque ele será criado implicitamente se nenhum outro construtor for criado. Se o fizer nada atrapalha, ele será preenchido com as atribuições de todos os campos, conforme já explicado. Ele precisa ser declarado explicitamente se precisa chamá-lo em algum lugar desta forma e tem outra sobrecarga impedindo que o compilador crie um para você. E este parece ser o caso na pergunta.

> Como o programa faz essa associação que construtor vazio quer dizer *setar* todos os atributos para valores padrão?

Justamente porque todos eles precisam ser *setados* e o vazio não fazendo nada só fará todas as atribuições e mais nada.

O compilador escreve um código para você, como se você tivesse escrito.

Já falaram sobre diminuição da visibilidade e isso pode ser importante, ainda que a pergunta não demonstre interesse nisso, não vou entrar neste ponto.

## Seu código

Me parece inadequado esse construtor vazio no código da pergunta. Porque no momento que o chama e não tem inicialização nas propriedades, nem mesmo permite a inicialização com `init` ou obrigar com `required`, até porque na época da pergunta não existiam, os seus respectivos campos não podem ficar sem inicialização e serão inicializados com seu construtor vazio com o valor padrão.

Acontece que o valor padrão é inútil e até deixa o objeto em um estado que pode ser considerado inválido.

Ainda falta real contexto, mas provavelmente o construtor resolveu um problema e causou outro. Eu acho que ele deveria ser excluído e só com dados válidos deveria poder criar um objeto `Pessoa`.

Tentando analisar mais especificamente, se o campo `Nome` pode ser nulo e o objeto ainda ser considerado válido, por que o `DataNascimento` também não pode? Não faz sentido um inicializar como nulo e o outro com a primeira data existente no nosso sistema. Se o campo `DataNascimento` está certo em ter uma data sem sentido real, mas inicializada, então o `Nome` provavelmente deveria fazer o mesmo, e deveria constar uma *string* vazia e não um nulo.

Portanto o construtor vazio não parece fazer sentido. Ele está fazendo justamente o que um construtor não deveria fazer que é deixar o objeto ser construído em estado inválido.

Se for para fazer de forma inválida eu faria, em versões antigas:

```
public class Pessoa {
    public string Nome { get; set; } = "";
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public Pessoa() {}
    public Pessoa(string nome, DateTime dtNasc) {
        Nome = nome;
        DataNascimento = dtNasc;
    }
}
```

Mas eu ligaria a verificação de nulo de C# 8. Se isto não for possível eu verificaria se `nome` é nulo e não atribuir isso neste caso, caso contrário o código continuaria funcionando no caminho feliz, mas errado em outras circunstâncias.

O mesmo pode ser obtido assim:

```
public class Pessoa {
    public string Nome { get; set; };
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public Pessoa() => Nome = "";
    public Pessoa(string nome, DateTime dtNasc) {
        Nome = nome;
        DataNascimento = dtNasc;
    }
}
```

Se puder fazer algo moderno e mais correto:

```
public class Pessoa {
    public string Nome { get; required; };
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; required; }
}
```

Ou se realmente quiser que o dado possa ser opcional e inicialize com valor padrão:

```
public class Pessoa {
    public string Nome { get; init; };
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; init; }
}
```

Assim, não precisa do construtor e não permite dados inválidos:

```
Pessoa pessoa = PessoaController.Obter(id) ?? new() { Nome = "João", DataNascimento = DateTime(2000, 10, 10) };
```

Continuando, algumas coisas que eu modificaria, mesmo não sabendo seu real contexto (lembrando que vejo vários problemas de confiabilidade, de [vazamento de abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101) e outros nesse código):

```
public class Faculdade {
    public Pessoa Mantenedor { get; set; } = new Pessoa();
    public List<Aluno> Alunos { get; set;} = new List<Aluno>();
    public List<Disciplina> Disciplinas { get; set; } = new List<Disciplina>();
}
```

Só para deixar do jeito ruim, mas sem o construtor, o que dá na mesma:

```
public class Aluno {
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int RM { get; set; }
    public bool Sexo { get; set; }          
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Constructor.cs).

Answer (score 1):

> Como o programa faz essa associação que construtor vazio quer dizer setar todos os atributos para valores padrão?

Isso não é verdade, o construtor vazio não quer dizer que os atributos das classes serão inicializados com valores padrão, quer dizer apenas que o objeto pode ser criado sem alteração de seus atributos.

Todo atributo que pertence à classe possui valores padrão independente de como for especificado seu construtor.

Entretanto, o mesmo não se aplica para atributos que pertencem a métodos, pois nesse caso existe a obrigatoriedade de serem inicializados explicitamente. Caso você tente usar um atributo de um método sem inicializá-lo você obterá um erro de compilação.

Answer (score 0):

Se o construtor da sua classe é vazio, não há necessidade de especificá-lo.

Classes que não possuem construtores a princípio são de objetos que não demandam valores obrigatórios para existirem quando são instanciados.

para iniciar o valor de um campo privado na sua classe, voce pode fazê-lo sem precisar de um construtor:

```
public class Faculdade
{
    private Pessoa mantenedor_ = new Pessoa();
    private List<Aluno> alunos_ = new List<Aluno>();
    private List<Disciplina> disciplinas_ = new List<Disciplina>();

    public // propriedades ...
}
```