# Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, classes, struct

Qual a diferença entre `Struct` e `Class`?

Que tipo de situação devo utilizar uma `Struct` invés de uma `Class`?

Comment: Essa pergunta minha http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14490/alocacao-de-memoria-em-c-tipos-valor-e-tipos-referencia é sobre tipos valor e tipos referência e essa http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15510/o-que-imutavel-realmente-significa é sobre imutabilidade. Acho que vendo as duas você vai entender a diferença.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

## Resumo

- `Struct`s são tipos por valor (Seção 11.3.1).
- Todos os tipos `struct` implicitamente herdam da classe `System.ValueType` (Seção 11.3.2).
- Atribuição a uma variável do tipo `struct` cria uma cópia do valor sendo atribuído (Seção 11.3.3).
- O valor padrão de uma `struct` é o valor produzido após atribuir todos os tipos valores para seu valor padrão e todos os tipos referência para `null` (Seção 11.3.4).
- Operações de *boxing* e *unboxing* são usadas para converter entre um tipo `struct` e um objeto (Seção 11.3.5).
- O significado da palavra-chave `this` é diferente para `struct`s (Seção 11.3.6).
- Não é permitido que declarações de campos de instância para uma `struct` incluam inicializadores de variáveis (Seção 11.3.7).
- <strike>Uma `struct` não pode declarar um construtor de instância sem parâmetros</strike> (Seção 11.3.8).
- Uma `struct` não pode declarar um destrutor (Seção 11.3.9).

Este resumo é uma tradução da [documentação da Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55979&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e foi realizada pelo [mgibsonbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/215/mgibsonbr). Mas ele teve seus motivos para remover a resposta postada. Coloquei aqui porque é uma forma que ajuda os usuários.

## Detalhamento

### `Struct`

`Struct`s são usadas para criar estruturas de dados cujas instâncias (os objetos) sejam pequenas (no **máximo 16 bytes**), sejam [**imutáveis**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101), representem um **valor único**, ou seja, que não contenha diversas características, e **não precise ser encapsulado** (*boxing*) em objetos por referência com frequência. Estas estruturas têm seu conteúdo (seu valor) integral copiado quando precisa transportar de um local para outro. Portanto são tipos por valor (*value types*).

#### Cópia de valores

O fato de **todos os membros serem copiados** facilita o seu uso em ambientes concorrentes. Há garantia que uma instância será acessada exclusivamente pela *thread* que está em execução. Só é preciso ter cuidado com `struct`s que contém referências dentro dela. Os objetos referenciados não estão "protegidos" contra acesso concorrente. Uma `struct` não é segura em ambiente concorrente só porque é uma `struct`, depende de como ela foi definida pelo programador. A atomicidade, por exemplo, não é garantida intrinsecamente.

#### Herança

Além disso, `struct`s **não permitem herança**, ainda que uma `struct` seja sempre derivada implicitamente de uma classe chamada [`ValueType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx) que por sua vez é derivada de outra classe `Object` como qualquer tipo no [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101).

Como assim, uma `struct` é derivada de uma classe? Sim, `ValueType` é uma classe abstrata e `Object` só contém comportamento e não estado. Não existe nada de estranho nisso, estas classes apenas fazem parte da hierarquia do tipo. Então [está fazendo subtipo, mas não subclasse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152266/101). É como se tivesse herdando apenas de uma `interface`.

Não existe nada que obrigue qualquer tipo por valor ser herdado só por tipos por valor, na verdade isto nem é possível. Claro que se existisse estado seria mais complicado, afinal o estado teria que ser armazenado em algum lugar e é esperado que ele seja acessado por uma referência. No caso sem estado a referência não importa. Apenas o comportamento é herdado pelo tipo por valor, ou seja, o tipo por valor pode chamar diretamente um método definido e/ou implementado nestas classes superiores, nada mais que isto, ele não recebe estado.

Herança indica apenas uma forma de relacionamento "é um" entre a base e a derivada e não implica em mudança na forma do armazenamento (por referência ou por valor) do estado que será definido pela estrutura derivada. Obviamente que a derivada não pode ter menos coisas que a base.

#### Outras limitações

- <strike>Uma `struct` **não pode ter um construtor sem parâmetros** (chamado de *default*)</strike> (Agora pode). Na prática existe um construtor padrão, mas o programador não pode defini-lo por conta própria em C# (isto não é verdade para o CLR e outras linguagens que podem usar outra forma. Isto precisa ser entendido quando vai se fazer interoperabilidade com linguagens diferentes do CLR). leia mais [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14334/215).
- Quando um objeto (uma instância) `struct` é criado, seu valor precisa ser inicializado sempre. A inicialização se dá através dos valores padrão de todos os membros da `struct`.
- Também **não possuem destrutores**. Uma `struct` é destruída quando ela sai de escopo, quando ela não é mais necessária como variável local ou quando um outro objeto que contém a `struct` é destruído.

#### Onde eles são usados

As `structs` existentes no .NET dão uma ideia de como estes tipos devem definir dados com uma característica única, devem representar um dado único. Exemplos: `int`, `double`, `bool`, `Decimal`, `DateTime`.

O último mostra que uma informação simples pode ter partes, no caso a data e a hora, mas ainda assim é um dado único. Diferente de um calendário que possui diversas informações relacionadas. `Calendar` é uma classe e não uma `struct`.

### `Class`

`Class`es são usadas para todos os casos que uma `struct` pode trazer problemas, principalmente quando não atendem as recomendações acima. E elas são muito mais comuns nas aplicações.

#### Evitar cópia

É comum você ter objetos que possuem várias características e consequentemente, são maiores. Como os objetos são grandes, fazer cópias pode se tornar muito custoso em termos de processamento, pode desperdiçar memória e colocar pressão no *garbage collector*, por isso esses objetos costumam ser mutáveis, ou seja, eles podem ter suas características alteradas individualmente.

Em objetos mutáveis é normal que apenas a referência é copiada. Neste caso, são tipos por referência (*reference types*). Nada impede que uma classe ou outro tipo por referência seja definida para trabalhar com objetos imutáveis. A classe `String` é o maior exemplo disto.

A destruição de um *reference type* é feita pelo *garbage collector*.

Seu valor *default* é *null* que é um endereço inválido da memória.

#### *Boxing*

Um tipo por referência, como é o caso de uma classe, pode ser usado para encaixotar um tipo por valor (*boxing*), criando uma referência para o seu valor. Esta técnica deve ser evitada tanto quanto possível. A criação dos tipos genéricos permitiu que este tipo de operação fosse largamente evitado.

A grosso modo isto é feito:

```
class BoxedInt {
    int value;
    public BoxedInt(int v) { this.value = v; }
    public int Unbox() { return this.value; }
}
```

Então o código:

```
int i = 1;
object obj = i;  
int j = (int)obj;
```

seria convertido para:

```
int i = 1;
object obj = new BoxedInt(i);
int j = ((BoxedInt)obj).Unbox();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Cast/Boxing.cs).

## Terminologia

Para entender alguns conceitos apresentados aqui, pode consultar outras respostas sobre o assunto: [imutabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13924/101) e [*Reference types* vs *value types*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15512/101) que são conceitos que se confundem com `class`es e `struct`s, respectivamente. Os termos não chegam ser intercambiáveis já que uma classe não é a única forma de criar um *reference type*, existem os *delegates* e *interfaces* por exemplo, e além da `struct` existe o *value type* `enum`.

## Abuso de `struct`

É comum programadores inexperientes darem preferência para `struct`s achando que estão otimizando alguma coisa, quando, na verdade, o resultado pode ser o contrário. Além disto sem tomar alguns cuidados, seguir as recomendações descritas acima, é comum ter problemas na utilização desses tipos. Só devemos optar por criar uma `struct` quando existe uma boa razão para isto.

Note que foram descritas recomendações para o que deve ser uma `struct`. A própria Microsoft as viola em vários exemplos dentro do .NET. Recomendação não é regra obrigatória. Você pode fugir destas características quando sabe o que está fazendo e tem um bom motivo para isto. Estas características são esperadas pelos programadores quando estão usando uma `struct` definida, portanto se houver um bom motivo para não segui-las isto precisa estar bem documentado.

#### Não é fácil entender as implicações de um tipo por valor

Apesar de poder fazer em uma `struct` quase tudo o que uma classe pode, deve-se evitar situações complexas que podem não ser tão ortogonais ou que podem ser entendidas equivocadamente. O conceito de cópia do valor é simples para operações simples, mas se torna complexo quando inserido recursos que não se adéquam bem neste tipo de dado, criando armadilhas. Um evento, por exemplo, é indesejável.

`struct`s são muitos úteis, podem otimizar código e dar a semântica correta, mas elas não são absolutamente necessárias. Java mesmo viveu sem elas até hoje (claro que algumas operações não são trágicas em performance porque a linguagem possui tipos primitivos que no fundo têm a mesma característica de uma `struct` do C#). Se o programador não consegue entender todas implicações de uma `struct` é provável que seja melhor ele optar por uma classe. Não é o ideal, mas é o mal menor.

| Característica | Struct | Class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tipo por referência ou valor | valor | referência |
| Pode ter tipos aninhados (enum, class, etc.) | Sim | Sim |
| Pode conter constantes | Sim | Sim |
| Pode ter campos | Sim | Sim |
| Campos podem ser inicializados automaticamente | Não | Sim |
| Pode ter propriedades, indexadores e métodos | Sim | Sim |
| Pode ter eventos | Sim | Sim |
| Pode ter membros estáticos | Sim | Sim |
| Permite herança | Não (herda de ValueType) é sempre selado | Sim |
| Permite implmentaçêo de interfaces | Sim | Sim |
| Pode sobrepor os construtores e operadores | Sim | Sim |
| Permite definir construtor default | Não | Sim |
| Pode usar generics | Sim | Sim |
| Pode ser parcial | Sim | Sim |
| Implementação do this | variável com o valor | referência só leitura |
| uso do operador new | opcional | obrigatório |

Agora tem `record` para complicar ainda mais, mas não vou falar disso aqui. E tem `ref struct` que faz algumas informações aqui serem meias verdades.

Comment: No seguinte trecho surgiu uma dúvida ? "Mas o comportamento é apenas herdado pelo tipo por valor, ou seja, o tipo por valor pode chamar um método definido e/ou implementado nestas classes superiores.". Por que os tipos por referências não podem chamar métodos das classes superiores supondo que existe herança entre elas ?

Comment: @DiegoFarias editei pra tentar deixar mais claro. Tinha um erro e aí ficou mais confuso ainda.

Comment: Então uma referência só é importante para acessarmos o estado dos objetos ? Porque o comportamento eu posso acessar sem ter uma referência diretamente.

Comment: @DiegoFarias Não, a referência é importante sempre que o objeto não atender os critérios do 1o. parágrafo do detalhamento. Tem exceções, mas a regra básica é esta. Não esqueça de ler os 2 *links* que tem na seção de terminologia. Não sei se leu o *post* até o fim, eu mostra que os tipos por referência são bem úteis e se a pessoa estiver na dúvida qual usar, é melhor evitar o tipo por valor, apesar de ele ser melhor em muitos casos. Escolher um tipo por valor por engano pode causar problemas.

Comment: Estou lendo todos os posts até o fim, porém, fico um pouco perdido com tanta informação, mas estou relendo para tentar entender melhor. Vi também, que você diz que programadores iniciantes usam muito structs sem saber o conceito do objeto. Eu mesmo já fiz muito isso. Hoje estou usando mais classes.

Comment: @DiegoFarias vai devagar, é muita informação mesmo. E se ainda tiver alguma dúvida que faltou algum detalhamento, pode fazer uma pergunta nova.

Comment: Maniero, na tabela do final da resposta diz que utilizar o `new` é opcional. Mas quando eu retirei o `new` e deixei o código dessa forma `MyStruct myStruct = MyStruct("something");` o compilador gerou um erro e só funcionou com o uso do `new`.

Comment: É, de fato ficou esquisito, preciso deixar mais claro isso, é opcional no sentido que tem sintaxe para não usar, não que que simplesmente pode chamar o construtor sem ele e funciona, apenas que alguns casos não precisa chamar o construtor.