# Declaração de uma interface com where

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, interface, genéricos

Estou estudando bastante *design pattern*, pois acho que eles resolvem muita coisa e é bem oportuno o estudo dos mesmos. Peguei essa declaração no site do Macoratti e confesso, não soube explicar a partir do `where`. O que isso quer dizer?

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
```

Answer (score 9):

Isso está declarando uma interface como você já sabe. Também deve entender que ela é genérica. Ou seja, ela poderá trabalhar com diversos tipos de objetos, desde que quando ela for implementada seja usado um tipo especificado.

Provavelmente você sabe que esse `T` entre os símbolos de menor e maior e que vem logo após do `where` é um *placeholder*. É o que poderíamos chamar de uma super variável. Ela não é uma variável de fato, mas é algo para identificar que ali vai ter uma outra coisa quando for usado de fato. Vou exemplificar:

Quando você usa `IRepository<Cliente>` é o tipo `Cliente` que será usado nesta interface.

O que o `where` quer dizer é que você só poderá usar tipos restritos, não pode usar qualquer tipo. No seu exemplo você só poderá usar tipos que sejam classes. Você não poderá um tipo que seja uma `struct` ou `enum`, por exemplo. Mas poderá ter classes, outras interfaces ou mesmo delegações (tudo isso são classes). É uma forma de garantir que determinadas condições do tipo sejam satisfeitas. Por alguma razão essa interface não se dá bem com outros tipos.

Você pode restringir ainda mais, pode usar um tipo específico. Poderia usar por exemplo:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : IEnumerable
```

Nesse caso você só poderá usar tipos que sejam enumeráveis. Pode ser qualquer tipo, mas ele deve implementar `IEnumerable`. Claro que esse é só um exemplo para você entender, não sei se faz sentido nesse caso específico. Seguindo o mesmo exemplo você poderá usar:

```
new IRepository<List>();
new IRepository<Dicionary>();
new IRepository<String>();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Generics/InterfaceConstraaint.cs).

Tanto `List` quanto `Dictionary` ou `String` implementam `IEnumerable`, então podem ser usados porque atendem a restrição imposta na declaração acima.

Mas não poderia usar:

```
new IRepository<Buffer>();
```

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ([traduzido](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)). [Veja também sobre a palavra-chave](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: Ou seja, o tipo da minha interface deve ser uma classe, pelo que eu pude entender e somente uma classe.

Comment: Faz sentido sim, era só mesmo para aprendizado, para entender o "treco".

Comment: Na verdade qualquer tipo por referência. Pode ser `class`, `interface` ou `delegate`. Tem esse macete, apesar de estar escrito `class`, não é só ela. Para entender a diferença melhor: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101

Answer (score 8):

`where T : class` é uma restrição genérica e significa que `T` deverá ser um *reference type* (uma `class`, `interface`, ou um delegate).

```
class StringRepository<string>{}
class EnumerableRepository<IEnumerable<string>>{}
class DelegateRepository<Func<string>>{}
```

A restrição "oposta" é `where T : struct`, que significa que `T` deverá ser um *nullable value type* - ou seja, qualquer `struct` excepto `Nullable<T>`.

```
class IntRepository<int>{}
class DoubleRepository<double>{}
```

Podes encontrar aqui uma lista completa de todas as restrições genéricas possíveis em C#: [Constraints on Type Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Comment: Postei um comentário e agora entendi o que você colocou. where T : class, eu estava entendendo que o tipo só poderia ser uma classe e você colocou que pode ser uma Classe, Interface, Delegate. É isso mesmo? Ou você quiz dizer que eu posso ter restrições de Class, Interface, Delegate e etc? Menos, é óbvio, o Nullable. É isso mesmo?

Comment: @pnet É isso mesmo, `where T : class` significa que `T` pode ser qualquer um desses 3 tipos. Os 3 exemplos que eu coloquei irão compilar. Na minha opinião, o nome da restrição foi mal escolhido, devia ter sido `where T : reference`, por exemplo.