# Quando uma String é considerada um tipo primitivo no desenvolvimento para a web?

Tags: java, aplicação-web, tipagem

Fiquei na dúvida em uma aula quando o professor falou que um tipo `String` era considerado como primitivo! Mas eu aprendi em Programação Orientada a Objetos  que apenas são primitivos:

```
Byte: 1 byte.
Short: 2 bytes.
Int: 4 bytes.
Long: 8 bytes.
Float: 4 bytes.
Double: 8 bytes.
```

Comment: String é sim tipo primitivo em inúmeras linguagens, inclusive algumas de nível relativamente baixo como Delphi/Object Pascal.  Os tipos acima são os tipos primitivos da linguagem C, embora com nomes diferentes. C++ tem ainda o Boolean e o wchar como tipos primitivos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É a primeira vez que leio isso, talvez o seu professor possa explicar com certeza o que ele quis dizer. Mas chutando, pode estar ligado aos parâmetros de uma requisição virem como `String` no Java, independente do tipo que estiver especificado, por exemplo, em um formulário HTML.

Para exemplificar, considere um formulário que aceita números entre um intervalo:

```html
<form action='meuservlet' method='post'>
    <input type='number' min='0' max='100' name='meu-parametro-numerico'/>
    <button type='submit'>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Se você quiser obter o valor de `meu-parametro-numerico` no servidor, primeiramente você deve recebê-lo como `String` e posteriormente fazer uma conversão para o tipo correto, por exemplo:

```jsp
// Omitindo imports.

@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/meuservlet"})
public class MeuServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                        throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Obtém o valor como uma string.
        String valorDoParametroNumerico = request.getParameter("meu-parametro-numerico");

        // Converte para um inteiro.
        // Omitindo o tratamento de exceções e verificação/validação
        // se o parâmetro não é nulo ou vazio.
        Integer valorNumerico = Integer.parseInt(valorDoParametroNumerico);

        // Faz algo com o valor numérico...
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso mesmo!! É dessa forma que eu venho pensando!!

Comment: Tbm achei isso, que o http só usa texto puro, não existe `int` e outros tipos, uma conversão deve ser feita ao receber os valores do form.

Answer (score 4):

Entenda que em aulas, materiais e principalmente na internet as pessoas fazem simplificações. Provavelmente seu professor fez uma simplificação. Ou aprendeu errado, e está passando pra frente, sei lá :P

Cada definição de termos precisa de um contexto. Quando você usa um termo em um contexto ele pode significar uma coisa, em outro contexto pode significar outra coisa, não pode ser o oposto, mas haverá diferenças. A linguagem Java poderia definir o que ela considera como tipos primitivos. É prerrogativa dela definir isto em seu contexto.

Mesmo que não fosse isto, ainda assim o Java poderia dizer que é, se quisesse.

O que você aprendeu em outra disciplina vale para aquela disciplina, para aquele contexto. Provavelmente neste contexto que aprendeu só são considerados primitivos os tipos em que a maioria dos processadores costumam ter instruções dedicadas para manipulá-los.

Na documentação do Java há uma definição de que o tipo *string* faz parte da linguagem e suportado diretamente pela JVM e pelo compilador, só isto. Mas não é definido como primitivo. Você pode ler mais sobre isto no [tutorial "oficial" da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). Muitas vezes materiais usam termos errados. E pessoas reproduzem isto. E aí outras aprendem errado.

Se souber inglês pode ler mais sobre [estes tipos na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type).

Algumas pessoas não gostam desta terminologia. O C# e outras linguagens nem a usam.

O que pode ser considerado tipo primitivo é quando o tipo é por valor, mas depende de contexto, não é tão comum.

O tipo *string* não é um tipo por valor propriamente dito. Ele é um [ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101) para a sequência de caracteres, por isso ele é um tipo por referência. Mas para todos efeitos e ele funciona como se fosse um tipo por valor, ele tem identidade própria e não é possível alterar só uma parte dele, é imutável.

Talvez a confusão venha daí.

Eu não se sei devia passar isto mas tem uma resposta que ajuda entender a diferença entre [tipos por valor e por referência, mas é em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101). Não confunda, o Java é um pouco diferente. A ideia básica é mesma mas o Java, pelo menos até a versão 8 não permite criar seus próprios tipos por valor. [Essa também pode ajudar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101) (ou confundir mais, sei lá).

Já falei disto em [O que é considerado primitivo em uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356647/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu sei claramente qual a diferença entre um tipo primitivo e um tipo de referencia como uma String (sequencia de caracteres) !! Decididamente na programação java mesmo que seja para a web os tipos primitivos da linguagem já foram decididos, como uma String seria um tipo primitivo  ? Não concordo!!!  Mas vou dar uma conferida nos links!! Obrigado por não desistir de mim!!!

Comment: Aqui ninguém tem nada pessoal contra ninguém, tudo é uma questão de qualidade da pergunta. Essa não está boa, mas está razoável, dava pra responder.

Comment: Sim senhor!! Agora vou dar uma olhada nos links acima!!

Answer (score 0):

Depende da linguagem!

Exemplo, em `C#` existe o tipo primitivo `string` e o Objeto `String`
porem no `java` somente existe o objeto `String`.

C#:

```
string tipoString = "casa";
String objetoString = "casa";
String objetoString = new String("casa");
```

JAVA:

```
String tipoString = "casa";
String objetoString = new String("casa");//Porem não funciona passagem por referencia como os demais objetos.
```