# O que é considerado primitivo em uma linguagem de programação?

Tags: terminologia, característica-linguagem, tipagem

O que é considerado **primitivo** em uma linguagem de programação?

Somente os tipos são primitivos ou outros recursos da linguagem também podem ser?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dei uma [resposta que ajuda (ou atrapalha) entender melhor a questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/575246/101), e pode até refutar um pouco o que eu digo aqui.

O termo não é muito bem definido então pode ser o que alguém diga que seja, por isso pode ser outras coisas, mas não vamos tão longe.

Sobre tipos primitivos o que se considera mais é o tipo que tem representação concreta no processador, por isso os primitivos reais seriam os tipos numéricos básicos com 1, 2, 4 ou até 8 bytes, sendo inteiros ou com ponto flutuante, incluindo o caractere único e booleano que não deixam de ser um tipo numérico, ainda que alguns deles possam precisar de uma construção em algumas arquiteturas. Então são tipos escalares e não compostos.

Há uma outra corrente que diz que o tipo primitivo é aquele que a linguagem dá tratamento especial, é considerado *builtin*. Nem sempre é possível indicar o que é tratamento especial, então mesmo que seja um tipo composto ele pode ser considerado tipo primitivo. Por essa definição *string* pode ser um tipo primitivo, ou um tipo decimal ou uma data que não deixa de ser uma escala, mas com tratamento especial que o processador não lida de forma direta.

Alguma definição pode determinar que o tipo primitivo é o [tipo por valor e não por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101), mas vejo isso acontecer menos e provavelmente errado.

## Confusão feita por linguagens

Java usou muito esse termo e onde ele tem um significado mais específico. Java foi sempre vendida como uma linguagem totalmente orientada a objeto, ainda que isso não seja nem perto da verdade, e tudo deveria ser objeto e representado por uma classe. Mas por razões de performance tiveram que fazer uma exceção e ter tipos numéricos que não eram classes, os tais primitivos.

Em versão futura (quem sabe atual quando estiver lindo isso) ela deve contar com a possibilidade de criar tipos por valor (`struct`) e teremos tipos que sempre foram tipos por valor e tipos por valor criados pelo usuário. Quero ver como eles vão chamar esses tipos porque eles não são objetos como definiram os tipos por referência e não são primitivos porque não possuem tratamento especial da linguagem, e não são escalares. É o que eu falo, quando se define algo errado fica complicado arrumar depois.

C# sempre teve `struct` e por isso ela nunca usou a ideia de tipo primitivo, apenas de tipo por valor, onde alguns possuem otimizações para o tipo concreto do processador.

C# tem alguns tipos de biblioteca com apelido na linguagem, então alguns consideram eles primitivos, mas [até `string` é assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3711/101), então não acho que possa ser considerado primitivo, já que ele é composto e por referência, ainda que tenha semântica de valor. Mas há quem diga que ele é, assim como `decimal` é, mesmo sendo uma composição e tipo por semanticamente valor. Mas `DateTime` que não tem um *alias* de tipo e é uma composição e é por valor, igual ao `decimal`. Por isso é complicado definir o que é um primitivo de fato, cada linguagem pode ter sua definição.

Em geral um tipo primitivo é [imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101), mas como não tem um definição formal não sei se é uma exigência, parece que não.

Por tudo isso as pessoas confundem tipo primitivo com tipo por valor. Parece que todo tipo primitivo é um tipo por valor (não acho mais tanto assim), mas nem todo tipo por valor precisa ser um tipo primitivo. Pelo menos por uma definição. Outra considera `string` um tipo primitivo por referência.

Não sei se outras linguagens usam o termo, mas tenha em mente que cada uma pode conceitá-lo de uma forma diferente.

Veja mais sobre o assunto em:

- [Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101)
- [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101)
- [Qual diferença entre Boolean e boolean?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160914/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Esse struct do C# é o mesmo do C?

Comment: É bem parecido, mas do C# é bem mais poderoso.

Comment: Essa conversa sobre primitivos me lembrou que em Java existem as "primitivas" de programação concorrente (`wait()`, `notify()`, etc) sobre as quais outros mecanismos de concorrência são desenvolvidos.

Comment: Primitivo vem de primata, é dizer que o conteúdo é "antigo" ou inicial. Também pode estar associado a estado de desuso ou depreciado.

Comment: Existe uma referência sobre isso chamada primitivas: synchronized, wait e notify, que são basicamente estados.

Comment: Para ser exato, encontre o primitivo dentro de um contexto, e considere que em um algoritmo, o mais primitivo seria o número em si, e em sua estrutura, dentro de seu contexto, o número, o primitivo seria o tipo: null, boolean.. etc. Primitivo é bem similar a premissa.