# Tipos como list e str são todos tipos primitivos?

Tags: python, tipagem, estrutura-de-dados

Listas, tuplas, dicionários, inteiros, float, bool e etc. são todos tipos primitivos ou variáveis compostas são diferentes?

Comment: Tire suas próprias conclusões: https://ideone.com/3EP9B0

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

Por uma definição são sim: [O que é considerado primitivo em uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356647/101), mas por outra não.

Não sei bem como eles oficializaram isso, acho que consideram, mas muita coisa da documentação de Python não tem base conceitual correta, então pode ser oficial para eles, e estar errado, eu acho que está certo se adotar a definição que a linguagem dá tratamento especial, como também ocorre com tupla e outros tipos.

Comment: Ok, então em c por exemplo pode ser?

Comment: Em C não existe esses tipos.