# O que é um tipo?

Tags: terminologia, tipagem, ciência-da-computação

Qual é a definição de tipo na programação/computação?

Faz diferença se está usando o tipo para variável ou dado?

Todas as linguagens de programação possuem tipos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou começar pegando um trecho da [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) para ter algo canônico:

> Em ciência da computação e programação de computadores, um tipo de dados ou simplesmente tipo, é um atributo de dados que diz ao compilador ou interpretador como o programador pretende usar os dados

<sub>Isso é só mais uma definição que mostra que [as pessoas usam o termo atributo de forma errada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). O tipo é um atributo de um campo, mas não todo o campo, como muitos usam.</sub>

O tipo é o que dá forma ao dado, é o que diz qual o tamanho que ele deve ocupar na memória e como deve ser sua composição, bit por bit, byte por byte, membro por membro quando for pertinente. Além de dizer quais operações podem ser feitas com esses dados.

Na verdade o mesmo artigo mostra que há maneiras diferentes de lidar com a definição de tipo:

- **Sintática**

  Um tipo é um rótulo puramente sintático associado a uma variável quando ela é declarada. Tais definições de "tipo" não dão nenhum significado semântico aos tipos.
- **Representação**

  Um tipo é definido em termos de sua composição de tipos mais primitivos - geralmente tipos de máquina.
- **Representação e comportamento**

  Um tipo é definido como sua representação e um conjunto de operadores manipulando essas representações.
- **Espaço do valor**

  Um tipo é um conjunto de valores possíveis que uma variável pode possuir. Tais definições permitem falar em uniões (disjunções) ou produtos cartesianos de tipos.
- **Espaço do valor e comportamento**

  Um tipo é um conjunto de valores que uma variável pode possuir e um conjunto de funções que podem ser aplicadas a esses valores.

As regras estabelecem limites de quais valores podem ser armazenados ali. Por exemplo um tipo booleano só pode o 0 e o 1 (em alguns casos pode mais).

Existem tipos que se encaixam bem com o que o processador é capaz de trabalhar, em geral os tipos numéricos são assim, com tamanhos de 1, 2, 4, 8 e até 16 bytes. Esses tipos são chamados de **escalares**. Alguns gostam de chamar de [tipos primitivos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356647/101), mas há discordâncias quanto a isto.

Em oposição a tipos **compostos** que são tipos criados para conter um conjunto desses tipos escalares e outros compostos. Eles podem ser estruturas heterogêneas ou *arrays* homogêneos.

Mesmo um caractere é um tipo numérico, sendo o mais comum ter 1 byte. Apenas a forma de representar se mostra como um texto.

Até um ponteiro é um tipo de dado numérico com uma semântica mais específica.

Objetos definidos em uma classe são apenas estruturas heterogêneas com uma definição clara das operações que podem ser feitas com este objeto.

Mesmo tipos numéricos podem produzir resultados de formas diferentes pela forma como os bits são organizados e como é definido que eles devem ser operados. Existe uma diferença entre tipos inteiros e com partes fracionárias, em geral em formato binário (o formato decimal pode ser definido de forma um pouco mais abstrata).

Até uma função possui um tipo, mas ele é vinculado ao dado que ela retornará para a chamadora.

Então tudo isso dá um significado para o valor contido ali, em geral através de um nome que pode ser usado em diversas partes do código de forma consistente. Um tipo é uma forma [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) de estabelecer as regras de uma forma de dado.

Partindo daí podemos começar estudar a [teoria de tipos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory) e o [sistema de tipos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system).

Uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é um local para um dado. Então ela tem um tipo, seja qual for a linguagem. Algumas possuem a filosofia de tipagem dinâmica, o que significa que ela tem *apenas um tipo*, ao contrário da crença popular que indica que ela tem vários tipos. A forma do dado é única para alcançar isso, o computador precisa de estabilidade. Esse tipo possui uma *tag* com um subtipo que é um tipo mais específico para esse tipo único.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).