# O que é a restrição "class" em um tipo genérico?

Tags: c#, .net, classes, genéricos

Na linha abaixo:

```
public class Tree<TItem> where TItem : IComparable<TItem>
```

Esta linha eu estou criando a definição do tipo `TItem` onde `TItem` implementa a interface `IComparable`, ou seja, estou criando uma definição de tipo genérico que implementa o que foi definido na interface `IComparable` como método e/ou propriedades.

Minha dúvida seria na linha abaixo, onde o tipo `T` implementa uma `class`. Por que uma `class` e não uma classe específica? Qual o objetivo em criar uma definição para o tipo `T` que implementa uma `class`?

```
public class Repository<T> : IDisposable where T : class
```

Comment: Você pode fazer `public class Repository<T> : IDisposable where T : classeExpecifica` mas isso faz com que `T`  deixa de ser genérico.

Comment: @ramaral não verdade ainda seria genérico, porque permitira qualquer tipo que seja descendente da classe especificada e não só a classe.

Comment: Obrigada @ramaral, ajudou bastante!

Comment: @bigown Obrigada pela correcção.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode usar qualquer classe e não mais que isto. Não pode usar tipos que não sejam uma classe, ou seja, [tipos que não sejam uma referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101) (apesar que essa definição não ser bem verdade mais porque existe agora tipo por referência que não é uma classe). De fato se pudesse usar qualquer tipo a restrição não precisaria ser escrita, mas neste caso tipos por valor não podem ser usados como tipo específico na classe `Repository`.

Apesar do nome, não são apenas classes que podem ser usadas, podem outros tipos por referência, como interfaces, delegados e *array*, mas não pode um `ref struct` (pelo menos por enquanto).

Leia mais na [documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Entendi, obrigada bigown.