# Como fazer uma estrutura (struct) em C#?

Tags: c#, c, .net, c++, struct

Como fazer uma estrutura em C# em que você cria um tipo?

Por exemplo, no C++ usamos:

```
struct teste
{
  int a;
  char c[30];
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro seria bom dar uma lida [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101) para entender como funciona a `struct` no C#, não é bem a mesma coisa que no C ou C++. Embora não difira muito.

Então neste caso dá para fazer algo parecido:

```
unsafe struct teste {
    public int a;
    public fixed char c[30];
};
```

Só dá para reproduzir o mesmo efeito com `unsafe`. Esta estrutura terá 34 bytes de tamanho (em código 32 bits), como é esperado. Mas na verdade não deveria fazer idêntico. Primeiro que código `unsafe` só deve ser usado quando há real necessidade e não tem substituto, e esta forma não é idiomática. Segundo que algo tão grande deveria ser uma classe. Isto pode ser melhor entendido no *link* acima. A forma mais idiomática seria assim:

```
struct Teste {
    public int a;
    public byte[] c;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/WZlM9A). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zuztfL). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Struct/LikeC.cs).

Note que os membros são explicitamente públicos. Isto é uma exigência do C#. A sintaxe do *array* é um pouco diferente e não permite estabelecer um limite de tamanho que poderá ser usado. Para ficar com mais cara de C# eu mudei o nome para usar maiúsculo que é o normal na linguagem e retirei o `;` final que é desnecessário. Ainda poderia ter criado um construtor que facilitaria a inicialização da estrutura e até poder criar uma barreira de tamanho:

```
struct Teste {
    public int a;
    public char[] c;
    public Teste(int size = 30) {
        if (size > 30) {
            throw new ArgumentException($"parâmetro deve ter tamanho máximo de 30");
        }
        a = 0;
        c = new char[size];
    }
    public Teste(int a, char[] c) {
        if (c.Length > 30) throw new ArgumentException($"parâmetro para {nameof(c)} deve ter tamanho máximo de 30");
        this.a = a;
        this.c = c;
    }
    public Teste(int a, string c) : this(a, c.ToCharArray()) {}
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/zAJn1X). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p0ZQKC). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Struct/LikeC2.cs).

Note que esta forma é um pouco diferente. A `struct` tem 8 bytes de tamanho (em código 32 bits), mais um *array* de **até** 30 caracteres (60 bytes mais o custo de alocação do objeto e outros propriedades do *array*, como o seu tamanho, por exemplo, afinal é um objeto separado e o `char` padrão do C# possui 2 bytes para funcionar bem com UTF, e na verdade cada caractere pode ocupar mais de uma posição, ainda que raro) que ficará sempre no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Lembre-se que `struct` não é usada por referência, então ela sempre será sempre alocada no *stack* ou dentro de outro objeto no *heap*. Há uma semântica diferente aí. Se precisar da semântica por referência, use uma classe (também pode usar um parâmetro `ref` em alguns casos). Em C# isso tem uma distinção clara conforme o *link* da pergunta no início da resposta.

Obviamente há um erro na última tentativa, conforme esperado.

Esta forma já não é mais compatível com uma `struct` do C/C++, embora tenha como compatibilizar com algum/muito esforço no lado dessas linguagens.

Como última otimização eu mudaria o *array* de `char` para `string`, um tipo melhor para isto em C#, não me preocuparia muito com o tamanho e transformaria em uma estrutura [imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101), que é o correto para uma `struct` em C#, usando propriedades no lugar de campos públicos e com nomes melhores:

```
struct Teste {
    public int Numero {get;}
    public string Texto {get;}
    public Teste(int numero, string texto) {
        Numero = numero;
        Texto = texto;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ibEHP8). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FFdHwo). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Struct/LikeC3.cs).

Agora sim parece C# na melhor forma.

Answer (score 3):

Mesma coisa que o seu exemplo, só que sem o `;` no final. Segue o exemplo:

```
public struct Livro
{
   public decimal Preco;
   public string Titulo;
   public string Autor;
}
```

Para mais informações, [confira esse link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ah19swz4.aspx).