# Erro ao traduzir código de estrutura de C++ para C#

Tags: c#, array, c++, struct, gerenciamento-de-memória

Estou tentando ler uma *string* de um processo, achei essa estrutura na internet:

```
struct name
{
    wchar_t nome[32];
};
```

Fiz dessa forma:

```
struct name
{
    public char[] nome = new char[32];
}
```

E está me retornando o seguinte erro:

> Não é possível ter propriedades de instancia ou inicializadores em estruturas.

Onde estou utilizando o `struct`:

```
ReadMemory<name>((0x4EFDE5C + 0x54) + (0x1E8 * (i + 1) + 0x24));

public static T ReadMemory<T>(int Adress)
{
    int ByteSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)); // Get ByteSize Of DataType
    byte[] buffer = new byte[ByteSize]; // Create A Buffer With Size Of ByteSize
    ReadProcessMemory((int)m_pProcessHandle, Adress, buffer, buffer.Length, ref m_iNumberOfBytesRead); // Read Value From Memory

    return ByteArrayToStructure<T>(buffer); // Transform the ByteArray to The Desired DataType
}
```

Como prosseguir?

Comment: `public char[] nome;`

Comment: @LINQ Não inicializar um tamanho não adianta para mim, pois eu preciso pegar o sizeof do struct depois.

Comment: Para quê você necessita da *struct*?

Comment: @ramaral Para ler uma string de um processo.

Comment: Se souber qual foi o "*encoding*" usado  é só converter [`byte[]` para string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1003275/2556111).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro, não tem como transpor a semântica de C para o C#. Nada que faça ficará igual. Tem várias diferenças, mesmo que pareça que seja a mesma coisa.

Não tem como inicializar membros de uma estrutura diretamente, tem que:

- ser em um construtor
- inicializar com um valor passado para o construtor (não pode ser o construtor padrão)
- inicializar todos os membros.

Assim funcionaria:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var nome = new Name(new char[32]);
    }
}

public struct Name {
    public Name(char[] nome) => Nome = nome;
    public char[] Nome;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Mko3a7). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dxskwc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Struct/ArrayMember.cs).

Se quiser pode fazer uma validação para garantir que o tamanho tem 32 caracteres. Mas como eu disse nunca será igual ao C. Também seria interessante verificar se veio dados razoáveis. Uma estrutura nunca deveria estar em estado inválido. Uma classe também, mas em estruturas é muito mais importante.

Uma forma de deixar a semântica um pouco mais próxima é usar um `fixed`, como [mostrado em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106470/101).

É possível dar outras soluções, mas sem contexto fica complicado falar alguma coisa. Pra falar a verdade o exemplo mostra que algo muito errado está sendo feito.

Há quem faça algo assim (eu não gosto por vários motivos, pra mim é gambi da grossa e ruim para a performance e consumo de memória)

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var nome = new Name();
    }
}

public struct Name {
    private bool inicializado;
    private char[] nome;
    public char[] Nome { get {
        if (!inicializado) {
            nome = new char[32]; 
            inicializado = true;
        }
        return nome;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MzptNA). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7AEs6G). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Struct/ArrayInline.cs).

Uma possibilidade é criar uma propriedade que faça a inicialização (C# 6 para cima), mas só se tiver apenas este membro, se tiver dois membros já não funciona. O exemplo acima funciona.

Em C# é precisa tomar muito cuidado com a criação de estruturas. Em C também, mas em C vale para qualquer coisa. Estrutura tem peculiaridades que muitos programadores não entendem.

Uma delas é que esta estrutura terá o tamanho dela de 4 ou 8 bytes dependendo da arquitetura e [você nunca precisa verificar isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199618/101). Como eu disse não é igual ao C.

Essa estrutura na forma como está é completamente desnecessária em C# e C também.

Eu melhorei o estilo, mas ainda tem coisas muito esquisitas no código.

Comment: Perfeito, estou aprendendo muito, obrigado +1

Comment: @Maniero Acho que essa forma não funcionaria para mim, atualizei minha pergunta, da uma olhada.

Comment: @Francisco eu respondi a pergunta feita, esta é outra totalmente diferente e nem sei se dá para responder, não só por falta informações, mas também porque vai ter que refazer tudo, o que é outro indicador que a pergunta é totalmente outra. E vou reforçar o que eu comecei, C#, não é C.

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta do LINQ

```
public char[] nome;
```

No C# você não pode inicializar um field dentro do struct, por isso você recebeu o erro.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609831/why-cant-i-initialize-my-fields-in-my-structs

Comment: Não inicializar um tamanho não adianta para mim, pois eu preciso pegar o sizeof do struct depois.