# Maneira mais rapida de adicionar um item a uma lista, a usar uma estrutura

Tags: .net, vb.net, lista, struct

```
Structure turma
    Public id_turma As Integer
    Public nome_turma As String
End Structure

Structure Disciplina
    Public id_disciplinas As Integer
    Public nome_disciplina As Integer
End Structure

Public Class F_Contentor
    Dim turmas As New List(Of turma)
    Dim Disciplinas As New List(Of Disciplina)

 Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    turmas.id_turma.add(1)
End Sub
```

Tenho este código. E da este erro:

> Error  1   'id_turma' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Trabalho_mod_16.turma)'.  C:\Users\AlunoP\Desktop\Trabalho modulo 16\Trabalho mod 16\Trabalho mod 16\F_Contentor.vb   50  9   Trabalho mod 16

Qual é a maneira correta de adicionar um item a uma lista, usando uma estrutura?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Muda para:

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    turmas.add(New turma() With { .id_turma = 1 })
End Sub
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/FormLoad.vb).

Você precisa adicionar um item, e atribuir um valor para ele. Veja a sintaxe do método [`Add()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Add__0_).

Idealmente seria melhor usar nomes mais próximos do que se costuma usar com a linguagem. Veja [recomendações para C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101) que são bem parecidas com VB.NET. Também poderia pensar em criar um construtor para a estrutura.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Irei fazer isso. :) 

(um aparte): Para este caso, era uma mais valia usar uma classe ou devo continuar com as estruturas?

Comment: Entretanto apareceu uma resposta que responde a minha pergunta :p. Mais uma vez, obrigado.

Comment: Depende do que você vai fazer. Pelo tamanho eu ficaria com a estrutura mesmo. Mas tem que analisar outros fatores, por exemplo a [imutabilidade](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101). Veja mais sobre [as diferenças](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101).

Comment: Onde tem uma resposta que responde? Não tem como responder sem conhecer o caso concreto.

Comment: A dada pelo Deivid Ramon. Mas ainda vou ler os tópicos que deste.

Obrigado.

Comment: Sim tens razão.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa começar criando uma Classe, não recomendo usar Structure para esse tipo de problema. Dá pra fazer uma lista de estruturas, mas é mais simples e funcional usar uma classe. Estruturas são ValueTypes, quando vc usa algo do tipo estrutura(0) = value, vc está criando uma cópia daquele valor, enfim, a não ser que tenha extrema necessidade ou restrição para usar uma strucure, use uma classe.

Crie a classe

```
Public Class Turma
Public Property IdTurma() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_IdTurma
    End Get
    Set
        m_IdTurma = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_IdTurma As Integer
Public Property NomeTurma() As String
    Get
        Return m_NomeTurma
    End Get
    Set
        m_NomeTurma = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_NomeTurma As String
End Class
```

E então instancie uma Lista dessa classe.

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Dim lstTurma As New List(Of Turma)()

lstTurma.Add(New Turma() With { _
    Key .IdTurma = 1, _
    Key .NomeTurma = "Turma do Barulho" _
})
End Sub
```

Para adicionar items à uma lista, basta usar o método Add, onde você vai adicionar novos objetos daquela classe.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda e resposta bastante completa. Provavelmente irei mudar o código para usar classes.