# Posso usar class e struct ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, classes, struct

Tenho uma variável "Endereco", porém, ela é composta por "Rua", "Numero" etc. A maneira que fiz abaixo é a melhor a ser feita? Com `class` e `struct` ao mesmo tempo? Ou existe algo melhor e mais simples a ser feito?

```
public struct Endereco
{
    public string Rua { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
}

public class Cliente
{
    public int idCliente { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Endereco Endereco_;
}
```

E aqui como eu chamo no form:

```
Cliente cli = new Cliente();
cli.idCliente = int.Parse(txtidCliente.Text);
cli.Nome = txtNome.Text;
cli.Endereco_.Rua = txtRua.Text;
//...etc
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não está usando ao mesmo tempo, está fazendo uma estrutura e depois uma classe. Não tem problema no geral, pelo menos não por existir ambos. Mas esse caso parece ser bem errado.

A organização está certa, mas o mais correto seria ter duas classes<sup>*</sup>.

## Por que não pode usar `struct` em `Endereço`?

Há dois "impedimentos".

Primeiro ela é muito grande. Ela terá 4 [palavras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185523/101) (considerando que não vá crescer no futuro). Em arquitetura de 32 bits são 16 bytes. Em arquitetura de 64 bits são 32 bytes. Só os ponteiros para o texto é que são armazenados na estrutura.

Isso é muita coisa, até está no limite do recomendado, mas pode crescer, não tem CEP, pode precisar mais coisas, como "complemento" ou "indicação de local". Estruturas só deveriam ter até 16 bytes. Eu já fiz uns testes e vi que dá bons resultados com tamanhos maiores, mas eu sei que estou fazendo e quando quer passar por cima da recomendação oficial, tem muita nuance, se não entender tudo, é melhor ficar na recomendação.

O problema é que estruturas são [tipos por valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101) e eles são passados por cópia, pode ser ineficiente se for muito grande.

Justamente por serem por valor as pessoas não entendem bem a semântica quando altera seus dados.

Quando você copia os dados de uma variável por valor (`struct`) é criado outro objeto, então se mexer em um não mexe no outro. E há muita cópia que a pessoa nem percebe que ocorre. No casos dos tipos por referência (`class`) a cópia é do ponteiro e não do objeto em si, então é sempre o mesmo objeto. Mexeu nele, todas referências para ele enxergarão a modificação. A resposta do Marco Giovanni mostra como isso ocorre.

Estruturas devem ser [imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101), **ou muda tudo e obtém-se um novo objeto ou não muda nada**. Não parece ser o caso de `Endereco`. Os dados podem ser alterados independentemente. De fato não há nenhum mecanismo protegendo disto.

Já prestou atenção nos tipos do C# que são `structs`? Tudo coisa pequena e indivisível.

## Há exceções

Se souber muito bem o que está fazendo pode abusar das estruturas para ganhar performance aliviar o *garbage collector*. Este site que está usando agora faz muito isso em seu software. No casos que precisa evitar a cópia ele usa o [`ref`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Que alias, com novos recursos do C# 7, tenderá ser usada cada vez mais em sistemas onde a performance e gerenciamento de memória importa mais.

Os novos recursos que estão vindo nas próximas versões ajudarão garantir imutabilidade, ainda que já possa fazê-lo agora.

Novamente, tudo pode se souber todas implicações do seu uso.

Note que algumas classes preferem ser imutáveis. `String` é o caso mais óbvio. Há quem diga que tudo deveria ser imutável e isso é feito em outras linguagens. Tem lá suas desvantagens.

Para entender melhor leia [Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101).

[O Eric Lippert fala em detalhes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/mutating-readonly-structs?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e poucas pessoas tem mais autoridade sobre isso que ele. O exemplo que ele coloca é ótimo:

```
struct Mutable {
    private int x;
    public int Mutate() {
        this.x = this.x + 1;
        return this.x;
    }
}

class Test {
    public readonly Mutable m = new Mutable();
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        System.Console.WriteLine(t.m.Mutate());
        System.Console.WriteLine(t.m.Mutate());
        System.Console.WriteLine(t.m.Mutate());
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZscUpa). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AOQYzY). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Struct/Mutation.cs).

O que ele faz? (isto é um quiz, responde antes de ver a execução acima)

1. Imprime 1, 2, 3 — porque `m` é `readonly`, ainda que isso se aplique apenas à variável e não seus membros.
2. Imprime 0, 0, 0 — porque `m` é `readonly`, x não pode ser mudado e sempre tem valor padrão 0.
3. Lança uma exceção quando tanta mudar o estado do membro, que acredita ser `readonly` (não está declarado, mas pensa que é transferido da variável para o membro.
4. Imprime 1, 1, 1. Porque como o dado é copiado em cada acesso, ele não usa o estado anterior. Quando usa `t.m`, você pega uma cópia do que está em `m`. `m` é imutável (por `readonly`), mas a sua cópia não é.

Pode existir problemas nessa abordagem, mesmo que use uma classe, mas não falarei porque não é o foco da pergunta. Também pode ter outros problema no código. Mas não há contexto, é difícil afirmar.

<sup>*</sup>Note que eu nem analisei se de fato o endereço deve ser uma entidade separada. Isso pode ser um erro no seu caso. Não tenho como avaliar isso.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. E lerei o links que você postou durante o texto. Obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Você pode apenas class, neste caso, pois a manipulação dos dados você vai estar manipulando apenas o endereço de memória:

Diferença entre **class** e **struct**:

**Class**

```
public class Endereco
{
    public string Rua { get; set; }
}

Endereco ex1 = new Endereco(){Rua = "rua xxx"};
Endereco ex2 = ex1;
ex2.Rua = "Rua yyy"

//Ambos vão estar com o mesmo valor, pois ex2, faz apenas referencia na memória de ex1
//ex1.Rua == "Rua yyy"
//ex2.Rua == "Rua yyy"
```

**Struct**

```
public struct Endereco
{
    public string Rua { get; set; }
}

Endereco ex1 = new Endereco(){Rua = "rua xxx"};
Endereco ex2 = ex1;
ex2.Rua = "Rua yyy"

//Não vão estar com o mesmo valor
//ex1.Rua == "Rua xxx"
//ex2.Rua == "Rua yyy"
```

Quando é usado struct?

Struct é usado geralmente em tipos primitivos e quando você precisa criar uma estrutura para fazer interopibilidade com outra linguagem.

Nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16181/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-struct-e-class#16183) você encontra uma explicação bem detalhada sobre as diferenças.

Comment: Você respondeu com um exemplo claro e consegui entender melhor a diferenças entre os dois. E vou ler o texto do link também. Muito Obrigado!