# O que é "palavra" de uma CPU?

Tags: terminologia, arquitetura-computadores, cpu

Na minha aula de Sistemas Operacionais o professor citou um termo que me deixou um pouco confuso, que é *palavra* de uma CPU (Unidade de Processamento Central) e ele não se aprofundou na explicação a respeito deste termo, disse que ela poder ter tamanhos diferentes em relação aos bits.

## Pergunta

Eu gostaria de saber o que é *palavra* e qual relação ela tem com a CPU?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Definição inicial

Palavra é um dado natural de uma arquitetura (processador).

Assim como em língua natural humana temos a **letra** como menor dado, a sílaba como o primeiro agrupamento do menor dado e depois a palavra vindo em seguida nas grandezas, no computador temos o bit como menor dado, e o menor agrupamento o byte (tá, pode não ser bem assim), e em seguida temos a palavra. Mas na língua as palavras variam de tamanho, atualmente todas as arquiteturas de computadores possuem palavras com o mesmo número de sílabas (bytes) e como as sílabas também são fixas, temos o mesmo número de letras (bits).

Quando falamos em palavra estamos falando de um dado que possui um tamanho/comprimento/largura de bits fixo que aquela arquitetura trabalha melhor.

Em geral estamos falando do tamanho do registrador do processador. Pelo menos dos registradores principais. Podem existir outros secundários para atividades específicas, tais como cálculo de ponto flutuante, vetores, criptografia, etc.

## Tamanhos

Pode variar de 1 bit (raro) até 512 (raro, poderá ser maior no futuro). O mais comum hoje é o tamanho 64. 32 também é bem comum. Em pequenos dispositivos 16 ou 8 ainda tem espaço. Nada impede de ter números quebrados, não precisa ser só potência de 2, ainda que seja o mais comum.

É comum, mas não obrigatório, que a palavra também determine o tamanho do endereçamento de memória máximo teórico. Se o maior endereço possível tem 32 bits é melhor o processador ter registrador com uma palavra de 32 bits para que o ponteiro caiba no registrador e possa ser feito o acesso de forma simples e rápida. Arquiteturas mais antigas e algumas muito simples (dispositivos embarcados) podem precisar de mais de um registrador para lidar com os endereços. Uma arquitetura que necessite cálculos precisos pode ter um registrador maior que o maior endereço possível (ex.: 64 de palavra e 32 de endereçamento).

Em geral esse é o tamanho que o processador trabalha melhor com números. Eventualmente um número menor pode ser tão eficiente, mas há casos que há mais consumo para fazer alinhamento. Um número maior precisará de mais de um registrador e é mais complicado para o processador lidar com isso, é mais lento e geralmente perde a atomicidade da operação.

Há arquiteturas que usam a palavra como medida para transferências de dados, mas novamente, só não é uma coincidência porque pode simplificar alguma operação.

Outro ponto é que o tamanho da instrução tende a ser o tamanho da palavra, pelo menos em arquiteturas RISC. Isso acontecia mais no passado, hoje a instrução tende a ser menor, pelo menos em arquiteturas com palavras grandes.

Alocações de memória costumam ocupar múltiplos do tamanho de uma palavra.

Há arquiteturas que podem ter variações de tamanho da palavra. No Intel x86, por exemplo, começou com 16 bits, depois passou para 32 bits e agora é 64 bits que pode ter esses 3 tamanhos de palavras, chamadas respectivamente de WORD, DWORD (*double word*), QWORD (*quad word*).

No passado uma palavra tentava ser igual ao tamanho do caractere, mas isso não faz mais sentido.

[Tabela de várias arquiteturas conhecidas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)#Table_of_word_sizes).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Uma explicação melhor que a outra

Comment: @DiegoFarias que bom que gostou, se quiser ver tudo o que eu respondi organizado por votos: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/bigown?tab=answers&sort=votes. Nem tudo vai te interessar, mas tem algumas coisas legais. Se quiser só C#: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a101%20%5bc%23%5d

Comment: Então, estou bem interessado em aprender mais, vi que seus posts vão levando a mais posts e referências que tem muito conteúdo bom disponível. Sou novo na área, mas pretendo dominar o assunto e fazer igual a você fala em alguns posts, não ficar comprando MITO. Conforme meu conhecimento está aumento, estou percebendo que alguns programadores que eu achava que eram Deuses, não são como eu achava =). Obrigado pela dica vou acompanhar sim. Vou tentar manter o meu acesso a plataforma com regularidade.

Comment: Não existem deuses, todos têm falhas, até os melhores, mesmo. Hoje a nossa indústria vive muito de mitos.

Comment: Sim, acredito que até os melhores cometem falhas, porém, bem menos que pessoas que não sabem o que realmente estão fazendo. Vi que no link que passou só de C# tem mais 940 posts para acompanhar. vou tirando um tempo e acompanhando os mesmos, esses conteúdos serão bem uteis para aprender mais e amadurecer o conhecimento já existem. Obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Os processadores respondem aos comandos do programa (ou, por extensão, do programador) através da linguagem de máquina, na forma de números binários, que representam 0 = 0 *Volts*  e 1 = 5 *Volts*, por exemplo. Essa linguagem nada mais é do que a interpretação de uma "tabela" de instruções onde cada instrução ("opcode") tem uma tarefa a executar dentro do processador.

Esses "opcodes" ou instruções são armazenadas na memória de programa (ROM ou RAM) e o processador vai lendo, decodificando e executando sequencialmente uma a uma.

Toda a sequência de eventos ocorridos dentro do "chip" do microprocessador, desde a energização do sistema, é comandada pelo relógio ("clock"), que envia pulsos aos componentes eletrônicos arranjados de forma a constituírem uma complexa máquina de estados. Cada 0 e 1 armazenado eletronicamente na memória de programa inicializa e põe em funcionamento essa máquina de estados, dando instruções para o próximo estado.

Normalmente são necessários vários ciclos do relógio para satisfazer (ou estabilizar) completamente o sistema, dependendo do tipo de "instrução" com o qual ele foi alimentado.

A quantidade de instruções desejada pelo projetista do sistema vai determinar o número mínimo de bits (zeros e uns) necessários para completar o conjunto dessas instruções. Assim, com 1 bit só temos 2 estados ou instruções possíveis. Com 2 bits, 4 instruções (00, 01, 10, 11). Com 4 bits, 16 instruções, e assim por diante.

Essa quantidade é a **palavra** do processador.

Mas quer dizer que com 64 bits são possíveis mais de 18.000.000.000.000.000.000 instruções?

Sim, mas para entender melhor o porquê dessa palavra tão grande, vamos prosseguir...

A operação com cada instrução é feita, normalmente, em duas etapas: **busca** ("fetch"), onde a instrução é transferida da memória para o circuito do decodificador de instruções; e **execução** propriamente dita. Veja [Ciclo de Instrução](http://Ciclo%20de%20Instru%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

Tomando-se como exemplo o microprocessador 8085, de 8 bits, as instruções mais rápidas, normalmente de apenas um byte, são executadas em quatro ciclos do relógio ("clock"), e as  mais  lentas, aquelas em que o processador necessita buscar na memória mais dois bytes de dados, em  até  16  ciclos. Ao todo, esse processador possui 74 instruções e o relógio chegava ao máximo de 5 *MHz*.

Como podemos perceber, os antigos processadores eram pouco eficazes com relação ao tempo de processamento de instruções. O maior desempenho pode ser conseguido: pelo **aumento da frequência do relógio** ("clock"), tendo limitações físicas (elétricas e magnéticas) dos barramentos (interligações); pelo **aumento do número de bits externos**, que também possuem limitações quanto ao espaço físico; pela **redução do número de ciclos para executar cada instrução**, o que atualmente é feito pelo encadeamento dos ciclos de busca de instrução com o de decodificação e/ou pela utilização de memória "cache"; pela **execução paralela de instruções** ou multiprocessamento ou, por último, pelo **aumento do número de bits processados internamente**, ou seja, a ALU (Unidade de Lógica e Aritmética) os registradores e o(s) acumulador(es) com capacidade maior: 16 bits, 32 bits, 64 bits...

Revendo a história dos microprocessadores, o primeiro, 4004 da Intel, tinha palavra de 4 bits. As instruções eram divididas em dois "nibbles", ou seja, 4 bits ou meio byte: o primeiro era o "opcode", o segundo o modificador. Mais dois "nibbles" poderiam compor o endereço ou dados de instruções maiores. Veja o manual em PDF desse chip em [4004 datasheet](http://www.applelogic.org/files/4004Data.pdf). Apesar de ele ter instruções equivalentes a um processador de 8 bits, só conseguia realizar cálculos (ele foi projetado para calculadora!) diretamente com não mais do que 4 bits.

Atualmente os processadores já não decodificam as instruções apenas por meio de dispositivos físicos de lógica, mas por microprogramas, e utilizam-se da mais avançada e complexa arquitetura.

Dentro de cada "opcode" está embutida muito mais informação do que aquelas antigas instruções. Além disso, o processador, aliás, cada um dos diversos processadores é capaz de manipular e efetuar cálculos com números com muito mais algarismos e casas decimais, em prol de uma maior eficiência.