# É possível descobrir com código o tamanho que o objeto ocupa na memória?

Tags: c#, .net, memória, objetos

Se eu precisar calcular o espaço ocupado para tomar alguma decisão tem como descobrir o tamanho que cada tipo ocupa para verificar quanto será ocupado de memória se eu alocar várias instâncias dele?

Claro que tem como fazer um conta, mas posso errar na conta, posso mudar a estrutura dele e não lembrar de mudar a quantidade total onde precisava, então preciso descobrir pelo código.

Também não adianta usar uma ferramenta externa porque preciso do valor na aplicação.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Depende do que deseja. Se quer saber o tamanho exato que ocupará é bem difícil. Se aceitar uma aproximação aí dá, mas não sei se a aproximação é tão útil.

A resposta do Denis dá uma aproximação.

Outra forma é pegar o tamanho do tipo com o operador [`sizeof`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/sizeof?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Se você sabe o objeto, sabe o tipo dele. Funciona até com genéricos. Se conhece C, funciona igual. Só que em C# ele é pouco necessário.

O valor retornado não inclui o [*overhead*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198252/101) que cada objeto tem para alocar no *heap*, se for o caso de alocar lá. A conta do *overhead* é um pouco complicada e pode variar de versão pra versão, ainda que nunca vi mudar. Hoje é o tamanho de duas [palavras de CPU](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185523/101). Se estiver na *stack* não tem *overhead*, quando está dentro de outro objeto *in place* também não.

Note que se o objeto contém referências, existem outros objetos que estão ocupando espaço também e é problema seu detectar isso e verificar todo o grafo de objetos.

Também complica quando tem *array* envolvido, aí você tem que perguntar pra ele o seu tamanho e multiplicar pelo tamanho do tipo que ele carrega.

O [*runtime*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101) faz umas mágicas. Sei lá o que aconteceria em casos assim. Não dá para confiar.

Na verdade tem tantas outras coisas que podem influir na ocupação da memória que é muito difícil saber isso de antemão.

Não gosto da solução do Arthur, Mathias e LINQ, ainda que seja o melhor esforço, porque também é impreciso, você não tem controle sobre o GC. A alocação não é tão linear assim. Se você pedir 4 bytes não vai mudar 4 bytes, pode mudar nada, pode mudar mais, depende da organização da memória e até de como o GC está trabalhando naquela versão. E se estiver na *stack* vai mudar nada, então pode parecer que o tamanho é 0.

Não considero nenhuma resposta aqui errada, só não há precisão e isso precisa estar nas respostas para completeza. Minha opinião.

Imagino que não está falando de memória não gerenciada. Esta pode ser identificada com [`Marshall.SizeOf()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_SizeOf_System_Object_).

Então minha resposta é que precisamente não dá. Impreciso dá mas não tem muita serventia. .NET não é uma plataforma adequada para esse tipo de coisa. Se precisar mesmo controlar a alocação vai de C. Até C++ pode complicar algumas coisas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: A verdade é que não há um método preciso para retornar o tamanho in-memory de um objeto.

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho sim. E estava até pesquisando pra ver se eu não comi bola.

Comment: Destaque para "*Não considero nenhuma resposta aqui errada, só não há precisão e isso precisa estar nas respostas para completeza. Minha opinião.*", concordo plenamente.

Answer (score 12):

Diretamente não é possível.

E eu ainda diria que o .NET não provê nenhum mecanismo em que seja possível obter esta informação precisamente.

Uma boa ideia, ainda que sujeita a falhas, é capturar o quanto a aplicação ocupa de memória antes e depois da criação do objeto usando o método [**`GC.GetTotalMemory()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) e então subtrair os totais.

Eu usei o código abaixo para testar e os resultados foram sempre os mesmos. No caso da lista com 150 mil itens, se manteve em **1050544 *bytes***.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var memoriaAnterior = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        WriteLine(memoriaAnterior);

        var listaEnorme = Enumerable.Range(0, 150000).ToList();

        var memoriaAtual = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        WriteLine($"Diferença: { memoriaAtual - memoriaAnterior }");
        ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
long size = 0;
object o = new object();
using (Stream s = new MemoryStream()) {
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(s, o);
    size = s.Length;
}
```

ou

```
object obj = new List<int>(); // objeto que quer saber o tamanho
RuntimeTypeHandle th = obj.GetType().TypeHandle;
int size = *(*(int**)&th + 1);
Console.WriteLine(size);
```

Esse método disponibiliza um tamanho impreciso pois inclui informações como: nome e versão da DLL.

Fonte:

1 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605621/how-to-get-object-size-in-memory

2 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128315/find-size-of-object-instance-in-bytes-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Denis se não me engano pra usar ponteiros em C# tem aquele esquema de ser `unsafe` no método

Comment: [Há vários comentários explicando que esta primeira resposta contém imprecisões](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605621/how-to-get-object-size-in-memory#comment9742265_3173599), e a segunda calcula o tamanho estático do objeto, não o espaço dinâmico de memória ocupado.

Comment: Só lembrando, que este não é um método preciso, apesar de ser o mais bem aceito pela comunidade Stack Overflow internacional.

Comment: O que importa é o aprendizado. Todos nós aprendemos alguma coisa aqui hoje.

Comment: Bacana ver que o pessoal se importa em manter a qualidade do conteúdo postado.

Answer (score 8):

Creio não ser possível medir diretamente o tamanho do objeto, mas aqui no [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mab/2006/04/25/how-to-determine-size-of-net-managed-object-in-memory-like-a-sizeof-for-reference-types/) eles deram a sugestão de medir o total de memória antes e depois de criar o objeto, desse jeito:

```
long tamanho_final = 0;
Objeto meu_objeto;

//Pega o tamanho da memória antes do objeto..
long tamanho_inicial = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
meu_objeto = new Objeto();

//e o tamanho depois da criação
tamanho_final = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
GC.KeepAlive(meu_objeto); //garante que ainda haja uma referência para o objeto na memória


MessageBox.Show(“Tamanho estimado “ + ((long)(tamanho_final – tamanho_inicial)).ToString());
```

Porém, talvez haja algum problema/equívoco no cálculo caso o sistema use várias threads. Aparentemente se uma Thread aloca ou libera memória no processo de medida do tamanho do objeto, pode acontecer de seu objeto ficar com tamanho negativo (o que obviamente não representa um tamanho real), segundo algumas pesquisas que fiz, então talvez não seja a solução mais viável caso seu sistema implemente várias threads

Answer (score 8):

Uma maneira de conseguir esse tamanho seria calcular a quantidade de memória que é utilizada antes e depois de criar o objeto na aplicação, essa quantidade pode ser obtida com o método [GC.GetTotalMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que retorna um `Int64` com a melhor **aproximação** do número de bytes alocados na memória.
Como tu mesmo reforçou na pergunta, pode haver mudanças na estrutura do objeto, mas acredito que o `GetTotalMemory();` se encarrega de não errar nos cálculos.

ref:[How to get object size in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605668/3954447)

Comment: Mais um bom exemplo!