# Como saber o tamanho de um objeto na memória?

Tags: java, jvm

Eu não estou atrás de um método/operador `sizeof` porque eu já compreendo que JAVA não possui isso, mas eu preciso de alguma maneira de medir pelo menos em média quanto um objeto gasta de memória, mesmo que seja usando algum tipo de debug.

Comment: Possível relacionada:[É possível descobrir com código o tamanho que o objeto ocupa na memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199618/28595)

Comment: mas ai é c# é bem diferente

Comment: "Possivel relacionada". Por isso coloquei assim, é o mesmo tema, e como são linguagens com funcionamento parecido, essa talvez possa dar uma ideia.

Comment: eu sei, mas o c# tem o operador sizeof , que é uma diferença crucial

Comment: Acredito que essa função pode te ajudar `getObjectSize(object)`, ela retorna o tamanho em bytes.

Comment: Esse método pertence a qual classe?

Comment: Para usar `getObjectSize(object)` da interface [Instrumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) é preciso implementar alguns passos. Coloque-os na resposta pois da forma que está apresentado não ajuda e nem soluciona a questão.

Answer (score 1):

Se o seu objeto for `Serializable`, você pode usar um `java.io.ObjectOutputStream` associado a um `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream` para medir o tamanho do seu objeto quando é serializado:

```
class Tamanho {
    public static int tamanho(Serializable obj) {
        try (
            java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
            java.io.ObjectOutputStream oos = new java.io.ObjectOutputStream(baos)
        ) {
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            oos.flush();
            return baos.toByteArray().length;
        } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
            // ignore a IOException que é levantada quando se fecha o oos
    }
}
```

Aqui estou usando a construção "try-with-resources" do Java 7, que fecha os streams por mim. Se você estiver usando Java 6 ou anterior, tem como transformar essa construção num `try` comum, mas como Java 7 já é bem antiguinho, fica aqui a resposta...

Comment: E se o objeto possuir propriedades `transient`?

Comment: Naturalmente, os objetos apontados por propriedades `transient` não vão ser serializados e seu tamanho não será computado. Mas se, apesar disso, eles forem públicos e serializáveis, você pode obtê-los e serializá-los explicitamente, e então somar todos os valores que conseguiu. Não é simples, mas estamos tentando fazer algo a que a linguagem não dá suporte.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar o método sizeof:

```
VMSupport.sizeOf(...)

public static int sizeOf(Object o) {
  if (VMSupport.INSTRUMENTATION != null) {
    return VMSupport.align((int) VMSupport.INSTRUMENTATION.getObjectSize(o));
  }
  return new CurrentLayouter().layout(ClassData.parseInstance(o)).instanceSize();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Se você utiliza o eclipse, talvez esse plugin lhe seja útil https://www.eclipse.org/mat/ .
Ele dá um relatório completo e ainda permite você descobrir se em algum ponto da sua aplicação está ocorrendo algum memory leak.