# Como saber o tamanho de um objeto em memória ? c#

Tags: c#

Só para contextualizar, estou aprimorando um buscador de imagens e preciso guardar a busca anterior na sessão:

```
public static void SavePreviousSearch(APIStandardSearchResponse search)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session[PREVIOUS_SEARCH_KEY] = search;
}
```

E chamo isso dentro de um processo de busca na qual eu monto um `APIStandardSearchResponse`:

```
SearchCookieController.SavePreviousSearch(APIStandardSearchResponse);
```

Depois quando necessário eu recupero esse objeto:

```
APIStandardSearchResponse previousSearch = SearchCookieController.GetPreviousSearch();
```

Gostaria de saber o espaço em memória(no servidor) que o objeto `previousSearch` está ocupando. É possível fazer isso com o c#?

Comment: Mas se a sessão está sendo armazenada em cookie, ela não fica na memória, é literalmente um cookie no servidor.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo é como um arquivo físico, tipo guardado no hd/ssd ?

Comment: Na verdade depende do modo que você escolheu armazenar, dê uma olhada aqui
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/introduction-to-Asp-Net-session/

Comment: Mas por que você está preocupado com isso? Está planejando armazenar um grande volume de dados em Session?

Comment: Então Leandro, eu tenho uma lista dentro desse objeto com outros 100 objetos(resultados de pesquisa) ai eu fiquei com receio pois cada usuário que pesquisar irá armazenar essa pesquisa na Session...

Comment: Não sei o quanto de memória esses objetos utiliza, para que no futuro quando aumentar o numero de usuários eu não ter esse problema

Comment: O motivo de armazenar não vem ao caso, mas é necessário armazenar de alguma forma.

Comment: Talvez dup https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199618/101