# Qual a diferença entre Marshal.SizeOf e sizeof?

Tags: c#

- Qual a diferença entre os resultados do método `Marshal.SizeOf(Type)` e palavra-chave `sizeof`?
- Quando se deve utilizar um ou outro?
- Quando há diferenças de resultados?

Comment: Isso responde? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199618/101