# Relação de tipos do Java ou outra linguagem com arquitetura do processador

Tags: java, memória, tipagem, arquitetura-computadores

No Java tem os tipos primitivos: `int` e `float`, que guardam no máximo 32 bits de informação, e também temos os tipos `long` e `double` que guardam 64 bits de informação.

Isso tem ou pode vir a ter alguma relação com os processadores de 32 e 64 bits? Caso eu crie uma variável `long` ou `double` para executar num processador 32 bits, pode dar problema?

Comment: Não pode dar problema porque um variável que ocupe 64 bits de memória vai ser guardada em dois endereços diferentes.

Comment: Acho que não tem a ver com processador, até porque java é uma linguagem de alto nivel. Isso tem mais a ver com a quantidade de informação que a variavel poderá guardar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nenhuma relação na maioria das linguagens, isso é o tamanho do dado e ponto. Em C, C++, Assembly (ainda que esta última não tenha tipos formais) e outras mais baixo nível o tipo pode ter o tamanho variável de acordo com a arquitetura, mas ainda não há relação direta entre o tamanho do tipo e a arquitetura, muito menos há obrigatoriedade seguir isto de acordo com a especificação da linguagem. Ainda assim alternativamente essas linguagens também costumam possuir tipos com tamanho fixo.

Esses bits da arquitetura tem a ver com o endereçamento de memória e não de dados, normalmente indica o tamanho de uma [palavra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185523/101) e em alguns casos um tipo pode querer se conformar com o tamanho da palavra.

Tanto é verdade que existe `long` e `double` em 32 bits. Claro que nessa situação pode haver uma performance um pouco menor, mas não necessariamente.