# O que significa a instrução "retn" com um argumento?

Tags: windows, assembly, return

É possível ver instruções de returno com um argumento, como isso é feito e como o valor de retorno é tratado? É para retornar um argumento na pilha?

[image: Immunity Debugger, NTDLL, Windows]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando o código vai retornar de um rotina ele deve especificar quantos bytes ele deve voltar na pilha mudando o registrador Stack Pointer (SP). Esse é o número que consta ali.

Note que os números são sempre múltiplos de 4 bytes que é o tamanho de uma [palavra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185523/101) na arquitetura então ele está voltando a quantidade de palavras determinada por esse número dividido por 4. Não esqueça que está em hexadecimal.

O `N` indica que deve fazer isso dentro do próprio segmento de código. No passado códigos em 16 buts só conseguiam endereçar 64KB e para conseguir mais memória era obrigado usar vários segmentos através de um endereçamento chamado distante (*far*) e aí usava-se a instrução `RETF`, a não ser que fosse só no mesmo segmento que usa o `RETN` (*near*). EM códigos modernos só há um segmento, mas mesmo no passado era mais raro sair do segmento para esse tipo de fim.

O `RET` na verdade é o `RETN` (ou `RETF` se for mesmo necessários), mas o montador infere quantos bytes deve voltar no ponteiro da pilha.

Isso é Assembly do x86, não vele para outros sabores.

Answer (score 0):

Pode-se notar:

1. É comum ter essa instrução no fim do Epílogo da função.
2. Quando ela usada, sempre altera o ESP e o EIP.
3. As vezes é utilizada para sair do "current segment".

Em breve retorno com mais informações.
Para referencia: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret