# Como determinar o tamanho total de memória em um processador de 4 Bits com barramento de endereços de 8 Bits?

Tags: memória, arquitetura-de-software, ciência-da-computação, bits

Sei que se um processador possui 8 bits, com registradores e barramento de dados de 8 bits, e cada endereço de memória armazena palavras de 8 bits, o tamanho total da memória é determinado pelo tamanho do barramento de endereços. Se o barramento de endereços for de 8 bits, teríamos 256 bytes; se fosse de 16 bits, seriam 64 KB; e se fosse de 32 bits, seriam 4 GB. Porém se temos um processador de 4 bits com um barramento de endereços de 8 bits, entendi que ele trabalharia com palavras de 4 bits (meio byte) e poderia endereçar 256 posições. No entanto, fico em dúvida se esse processador possui efetivamente 256 bytes de memória endereçável, considerando que cada endereço de memória só possuiria meio byte. Como determinar o tamanho total da memória nesse cenário?

Comment: *Quantidade Total de Memória* não é mesmo que *Memória Endereçável*, é possível contornar o limite de memória endereçável usando recursos como [paginação de memória](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagina%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_mem%C3%B3ria). No caso quando fala em processador com palavras de 4 bits você estaria se referindo ao processado [Intel 4004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_4004)? Caso sim, processado Intel 4004 possuía **barramento para transferência de endereços de 12 bits** , instruções de 8 bits, palavras de dados de 4 bits; então manipulava diretamente 4095 endereços mas não o limite.

Comment: Tem esse site [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) que é um Q&A irmão nosso, também pertencente a rede Stack Exchange, que é um Perguntas e Respostas, na língua inglesa, para entusiastas de computadores antigos interessados em restaurar, preservar e usar os computadores clássicos e sistemas de jogos do passado. Antes de usar aquele site veja as [regras](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Uma observação sobre você falar em "meio byte": byte não implica em 8 bits. Octet / Octeto é o termo usado para bytes de 8 bits. Troca-se um por outro por costume, mas nem sempre vai ser verdade (quase sempre vai ser, entretanto). Veja as várias menções a byte na terminologia da ISO https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/en/#iso:std:63598:en

Answer (score 0):

O total de memória endereçável de forma direta é de 256 bytes. O total de memória do computador não temos como saber sem olhar.

Se a [palavra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185523/101) do processador é 4 bits é irrelevante porque a memória é usada para armazenar alguma coisa e sempre vai permitir 256 bytes. Um byte continua tendo 8 bits (tipicamente, não temos mais informações se é alguma exceção aqui, geralmente não é, e se for, aí muda tudo). Um caractere costuma ter 1 byte inteiro, em alguns casos mais, mas duvido em uma arquitetura assim. Uma cor ampla como temos em um computador moderno precisa de pelo menos 3 bytes. Um inteiro que permite pouco mais de 4 bilhões de combinações ocupa 4 bytes. Nada disso muda com o tamanho da palavra do processador.

Se a questão fosse saber quantas palavras cabem, aí teríamos que saber como cada palavra é armazenada. Se ela realmente é armazenada com 4 bits, então permitiria 512 palavras. Porém isso é bem teórico, na prática essa informação não serve para nada real.

Comment: Peço desculpas se minha explicação anterior não foi clara . O processador em questão é um processador teórico. Minha dúvida surgiu porque sei que um processador com barramento de endereços de 32 bits é limitado ao endereçamento de apenas 4 GB. Porém, uma CPU com barramento de endereços de 32 bits em geral possui mais do que 8 bits em seu barramento de dados, sendo 32 bits comuns no barramento de dados para esses casos. Logo no meu entendimento, mesmo com o número de endereços limitado a 4.294.967.296, poderíamos ter uma memória RAM possível de até 4 x 4.294.967.296, o que representaria  16 GB.

Comment: Não consigo imaginar de onde tirou essa conclusão.