# Lists repetindo último item adicionado

Tags: c#, .net, lista, objetos

estava estudando sobre as *lists* em C# e não consegui entender o que está errado no meu código (provavelmente vai ser algo bem básico), todos os itens ficam iguais ao último item adicionado. Eu simplifiquei o código pra focar só nessa parte do erro, eu estou fazendo algo errado? Pelo q vi pra adicionar é só usar o `List.Add()`, mas não está dando certo. Também existe outra classe no projeto, a classe `Itens`, que tem a variável `nomes` usada no código (e só essa variável).

Deixei todo o código no `Main()` pra ficar menorzinho.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Itens itens = new Itens();
        List<Itens> list = new List<Itens>();

        itens.nome = "GPU";
        list.Add(itens);

        itens.nome = "Livro";
        list.Add(itens);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Item: " + list[i].nome);
            //Aqui ele imprime tudo igual a ultima string adicionada
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso é porque ele insere a referência para o objeto, não o objeto propriamente dito. Quando você for inserir, você precisa criar uma nova referência para o objeto `Itens`, com o `new`.

Comment: Imagina que cada item é uma caixa. O que tu vai adicionar é uma referência pra onde está essa caixa na lista (não a caixa em si).
O que o `new` faz é "criar uma nova caixa" pra armazenar essa informações e, consequentemente, uma nova referência pra onde você pode achá-lo.

Comment: Tipo os ponteiros em C, certo?

Comment: Basicamente, sim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var list = new List<Item>() {
            new Item() { Nome = "GPU" },
            new Item() { Nome = "Livro" }
        };
        list.Add(new Item() { Nome = "Cadeira" });
        var item = new Item() { Nome = "Abóbora" };
        list.Add(item);
        var carro = new Item() { Nome = "Carro" };
        list.Add(carro);
        item = new Item() { Nome = "Outro objeto" };
        list.Add(item);
        list.Add(carro);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
            WriteLine($"Item: {list[i].Nome}");
        }
    }
}

public class Item {
    public string Nome;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/A5xVbW). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WmKeFZ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/AddNewItem.cs).

Não estava adicionando itens diferentes, estava adicionando o mesmo item, portanto só ficava o último valor. Tem que criar um novo item para poder adicionar à lista. Quando fazia:

```
itens.nome = "Livro";
```

estava mudando o valor do mesmo objeto criado antes, então o item anterior apontava para este mesmo objeto, mas agora com um valor novo.

Isso corre porque as classes são tipos por referência, então o que tem na variável é um ponteiro para o objeto em outro lugar. Parece que são duas coisas, mas é o mesmo. Se fosse uma `struct` aí seria diferente, por isso que se fosse um inteiro o mesmo não ocorreria. Leia mais em [Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101).

Note que apresentei novas formas de escrever isso. Quando cria a lista já pode criar os itens *inline* e fazer a lista iniciar já com os itens.

Depois eu adicionei um novo item criando ele *inline* novamente, ou seja, não precisa criar uma variável para ele. Nem precisa atribuir valores para seus membros depois que o objeto foi criado.

Mas também fiz com a criação da variável se ela for importante. Novamente, tem que criar um novo objeto.

Vamos dizer que queira outra variável que segure um objeto e adicionar uma referência para este objeto na lista, fiz isto com `carro`.

Por fim, eu criei um novo item na mesma variável. Claro que a variável perde a referência para o objeto anterior, mas mostrei que o importante é criar o novo objeto e não a variável.

Ainda adicionei a variável `carro` novamente, mesmo sem mexer nada no objeto. É o mesmo objeto que está sendo adicionado, não é outro. Se mexer neste objeto, as duas entradas na lista serão afetadas, porque elas referenciam o mesmo objeto.

Se conhece os ponteiros do C, é isso. Tipos por referência são sempre ponteiros para objetos. Tipos por valor são os próprios objetos. Em C# se torna mais abstrato, mas o mecanismo interno é igual ao C.

Então note que seu `itens` não é um objeto, é uma variável que tem um valor, no caso um ponteiro, o objeto não está em itens. É um erro comum as pessoas acharem que variáveis sempre sustentam objetos. Isso só é verdade em tipos por valor.

Mudei o nome da classe que faz mais sentido, ela é só um item, a lista é que são vários itens.

Answer (score 3):

Tente adicionar os itens dessa forma. Acredito que vai resolver seu problema.

```
list.Add(new item{ nome = "GPU" });
list.Add(new item{ nome = "Livro" });
```

Answer (score 2):

É como [Felipe Avelar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1333/felipe-avelar) falou, você está apenas alterando uma propriedade do objeto `itens` e inserindo ele várias vezes; precisaria inserir um objeto diferente para cada posição:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Itens> list = new List<Itens>();

        Itens itensGpu = new Itens();
        itens.nome = "GPU";
        list.Add(itensGpu);

        Itens itensLivro = new Itens();
        itens.nome = "Livro";
        list.Add(itensLivro);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Item: " + list[i].nome);
            //Aqui ele imprime tudo igual a ultima string adicionada
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```