# Uso de struct no C#

Tags: c#, array, orientação-a-objetos, struct, modelagem

Tenho que gravar informações de clientes. E eu usei `struct` pra fazer isso. Vale a pena fazer isso? É ou não uma boa pratica?

[image: criei as seguintes variaveis public string dentro do struct]

[image: fiz um array do struct que criei com 110 posicões]

[image: adiciones as seguintes informações para cada variavel da posição 0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De forma geral não, este parece ser um caso claro para uma classe, não só por causa do seu tamanho, mas também porque não há identidade nele. Já dei uma [resposta que diz quando escolher uma coisa ou outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101).

Se precisar muito de performance e controle de alocação de memória pode usar sim, mas tem que saber bem o que está fazendo, tem várias implicações não tão óbvias, até mesmo para programadores experientes.

No C# 7.2 passou ficar mais fácil fazer isso desde que você use uma `readonly ref struct`, mas ainda não parece adequado para seu caso, já que ele deve permitir escrita direta no objeto em vez de criar um novo. Se por acaso a semântica for imutável mesmo, aí pode ser útil, mas não absolutamente necessário. O mais simples para um iniciante ainda será o uso da classe.

Answer (score 0):

O uso de **class** seria mais apropriado/eficiente. E como **Boa Pratica** use Propiedades ao inves de campos. Note que em c# propriedades *public* começam com letra maiúscula.

```
public class Cliente 
{
   public string Email { set; get; }
   public string Telefone { set; get; }
   ...
}
```