# Syntactic sugar?

Tags: c#, syntactic-sugar

Me deparei esses dias com o termo syntactic sugar, quando estava estudando o uso de `await` e `async` no C#.
Esse pergunta explica o que é syntactic sugar ou syntax sugar [O que é syntax sugar e como ela funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12964/o-que-%c3%a9-syntax-sugar-e-como-ela-funciona).

Além de `await` e `async`, quais outras existem no C#?

Comment: Acho que essa pergunta é ampla demais. Não existe uma fronteira tão clara sobre onde termina o "açúcar" e onde começa a "linguagem". Por exemplo, o operador `+=` também é açúcar. O `using` é uma versão adocicada de um código onde certos recursos são liberados manualmente. Vai haver dezenas de exemplos.

Comment: Eu ia perguntar justamente do using se era um syntactic sugar.

Comment: @bfavaretto Ter dezenas de exemplos não torna a pergunta ampla demais. Claro que a definição de syntatic sugar não é exata, mas mesmo que você considere até exemplo como `+=` (que não acho que sejam açucarados) a lista é finita e bem definida.

Answer (score 1):

É difícil separar exatamente o que é exatamente açucarado do que não é. Também é difícil definir todos os doces do C#, mas aqui vão alguns que deixam o código bem mais claro.

#### lock

Isso:

```
lock (_lock)
{

}
```

No lugar de:

```
object obj;
var temp = obj;

Monitor.Enter(temp);

try
{
    // body
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(temp);
}
```

#### foreach

Isso:

```
IEnumerable<int> numeros = new int[]
{
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5
};

foreach (int i in numeros)
{

}
```

No lugar de:

```
var enumerator = numeros.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    int current = enumerator.Current;
}
```

#### using

Isso:

```
using (FileStream f = new FileStream(@"C:\foo\teste.txt", FileMode.Create))
{

}
```

No lugar de:

```
FileStream f2= new FileStream(@"C:\foo\teste.txt", FileMode.Create);
try
{

}
finally
{
    f2.Dispose();
}
```

#### Auto properties

Isso:

```
 public string Foo { get; set; }
```

No lugar de:

```
private string _foo;
public string Foo
{
    get { return _foo; }
    set { _foo = value; }
}
```

#### Nullable

Isso:

```
int? nullInt2 = null;
```

No lugar de:

```
Nullable<int> nullInt = new Nullable<int>();
```

#### Operador `??`

Isso:

```
int myNum = nullInt ?? 0;
```

No lugar de:

```
int myNum2 = nullInt == null ? 0 : nullInt.Value;
```

<sub>Mudei a resposta para wiki da comunidade para que seja extendida e melhorada</sub>

Comment: Removi a minha resposta. Não entendo o porquê de fecharem a pergunta.

Comment: Concordo que é amplo, mas não amplo **demais**.

Comment: @ramaral [Este comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66282/syntactic-sugar#comment135375_66282) explica a amplitude da pergunta. Qualquer coisa pode ser considerada açúcar sintático, até mesmo redefinições que o próprio programador criar. Esta resposta mesmo diz que é difícil separar o que é do que não é. Assim, a pergunta poderia continuar recebendo dezenas de respostas e todas estariam, em princípio, corretas (o que não quer dizer que seriam úteis a qualquer leitor).

Comment: @LuizVieira Concordo com tudo o que foi dito no comentário, por isso é que criei a minha resposta como *wiki*. No entanto acho que foram rigorosos demais, até porque o AP pede por exemplos o que não obriga a nomear todos os casos.

Comment: @ramaral Eu entendo o seu ponto. Uma única resposta wiki certamente seria melhor do que uma enxurrada de respostas opinativas. Mas há de se considerar que o SOPT não é um fórum, e sim um site de Q&A que tem por objetivo ter perguntas e respostas concretas e bem delimitadas. Sendo assim, não acho que foi rigoroso demais.