# O que é uma meta linguagem?

Tags: característica-linguagem, paradigma-de-programação

Encontrei no [SO En](https://stackoverflow.com/) essa pergunta: [Creating meta language with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575085/creating-meta-language-with-java), no qual o usuário tem interesse em criar uma meta linguagem usando Java.

Fiz uma breve pesquisa e encontrei no site da Microsoft um tópico falando sobre: [Gramáticas, Linguagens e Compiladores: um retorno às bases](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wcamb/2008/01/13/gramticas-linguagens-e-compiladores-um-retorno-s-bases/), onde fala que:

> *[...].Em computação, uma meta-linguagem muito conhecida é a BNF ou “BACKUS-NAUR FORM“*

O que é uma meta linguagem?

Comment: relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178720/o-que-%C3%A9-backus-naur-form-bnf

Comment: Eu acho que a sonhada Gramática Universal de Chomsky é uma meta linguagem para definir gramáticas, mas meu estudo na linguística se focou mais no aspecto de compilação/identificação de árvores de sintaxe para uma frase em uma língua de gramática conhecida

Comment: Ué, porque o downvote? Será que poderia justificar, não haverá persiguição, o Acklay é uma pessoa bastante madura e sensata, só queremos entender qual exatamente o problema da pergunta. Grato.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Metalinguagem é a linguagem pra criar linguagens. Ou pelo menos é uma linguagem para criar códigos que geram códigos.

Meta é algo sobre aquilo mesmo. Assim como temos o meta SOpt que é um site de Q&A para, e sobre, o site de Q&A SOpt.

O mais interessante aí é o paradigma de meta programação que pode ser aplicado à uma linguagem dedicada a isso ou pode ser adicionada à outra linguagem.

Essa metalinguagem não precisa ser de programação, ou seja, não precisa ser [Turing Complete](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101).

No exemplo encontrado mostra uma linguagem de definição chamada [BNF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178720/101) que é usada para facilitar a criação e o entendimento da gramática de uma linguagem. Mas ela é limitada já que não pode expressar semântica.

Muitas vezes isso é confundido com [DSLs](https://martinfowler.com/books/dsl.html).

[Meta programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22398/101) é algo muito interessante porque pode evitar repetição, melhorar o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), simplificar código eliminando o [*boiler plate*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173190/101) e criar [*syntax sugar*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12964/101).

Mas também é algo bem complicado de fazer certo a não ser em casos mais triviais como o uso de [genéricos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101) (usado da forma normal como é comum<sup>*</sup>), o que já é um pouco complicado. Piora com [gabaritos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150181/101) e macros.

[Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)) é uma linguagem considerada de meta programação e por isso ela é tão fascinante. Ela provê os mecanismos básicos e um forte sistema de macro e o resto o programador vai "criando a linguagem". Muitas inspiradas nela também. Parece que a meta programação é a nova fronteira da programação e "todo mundo" está perseguindo isso em maior ou menor nível.

Existem também ferramentas de meta programação, como o [*scaffold*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119731/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

---

<sup>*</sup>Veja o comentário do Victor Stafusa abaixo mostrado que genéricos podem se tornar um drama também quando usado em todo seu potencial. Mas me geral ele é usado para uma substituição simples de um tipo genérico por um específico de forma "plana" e tem pouco a dar errado.

Comment: Eu não diria que tipos genéricos são "casos "mais triviais".

Comment: @VictorStafusa em que sentido?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.05274.pdf

Comment: @VictorStafusa não sabia disto, foi muito útil pras minhas pesquisas sobre linguagens, editei pra colocar isto. Verei se ocorre o mesmo com C#.

Comment: @VictorStafusa , e eu pensando que o generics do Java tinha alguma vantagem sobre o template do C++, mas com os dois podendo fazer tanto esforço assim, fiquei decepcionado

Answer (score 15):

Em suma? Uma linguagem usada para descrever outras linguagens.

BNF descreve regras de derivação para gramáticas livres de contexto, então é possível escrever qualquer linguagem livre de contexto (como a linguagem Java, ou mesmo a linguagem de definição de e-mails) com BNF.

[Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210716/64969) sobre linguagens livre de contexto, usei uma notação para descrever produções de um subconjunto da língua portuguesa, e também algumas produções de uma gramática sensível ao contexto.

Por mais curioso que seja, é impossível descrever uma expressão regular com uma gramática regular, e também é possível descrever qualquer gramática derivativa usando uma gramática livre de contexto.

```
P : L ":" R
L : N           #para gramáticas regulares e livres de contexto 
R : N
R : N t         #produção regular, se L for para N
R : S
S : (t | N)*    #forma sentencial, qualquer string de terminais e não terminais
L : S           #produção generalizada, para gramáticas irrestritas
L : S N S       #produção para o lado esquerdo de uma gramática sensível ao contexto
```

Note que essas regras definem até mesmo a meta linguagem para definir linguagens, com direito a alguns comentários meus sobre algumas características de algumas produções.