# O que é esse :object = " "?

Tags: html

Eu encontrei um trecho de código que eu não entendi o que faz.

Eu procurei, mas não encontrei uma resposta (ou não usei os termos corretos para pesquisar).

**Código:**

```
<div v-if="returnedObject" class="found-objects result">
  <Object :object="returnedObject"> </Object>
</div>
```

**Trecho específico que eu não compreendi:**

- `:object="returnedObject"`

Pediram que eu colocasse todo o código
**Código completo**

```
<template>
  <div class="found-objects devolutions">
    <div class="content">
      <label class="titulo">Devolver objeto</label>
      <hr />
      <div class="flex-column-between">
        <label>Entre com o código de devolução:</label>
        <div class="flex-column-between">
          <input type="text" class="input" v-model="devolutionCode" />
          <button
            type="button"
            class="button is-success"
            @click="returnObject()"
          >
            Devolver objeto
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr v-if="returnedObject" />
      <div v-if="returnedObject" class="found-objects result">
        <Object :object="returnedObject"> </Object>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      devolutionCode: null,
      returnedObject: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    returnObject() {
      let body = { devolutionCode: this.devolutionCode };
      let config = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + this.$store.state.token
        }
      };
      this.axios
        .patch("url", body, config)
        .then(response => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            debugger
            alert("Objeto devolvido com sucesso");
            let devolution = this.devolutionCode;
            let devolutions;
            let devolutionsStr = localStorage.devolutionsStr;
            if (devolutionsStr && devolutionsStr !== "") {
              devolutions = JSON.parse(devolutionsStr);
              if (devolutions && devolutions.length > 0) {
                let alreadyExistentDevolution = devolutions.filter(
                  devol => devol === devolution
                );
                if (
                  alreadyExistentDevolution &&
                  alreadyExistentDevolution.length === 0
                ) {
                  devolutions.push(devolution);
                }
              } else {
                devolutions = [];
                devolutions.push(devolution);
              }
            } else {
              devolutions = [];
              devolutions.push(devolution);
            }
            localStorage.devolutionsStr = JSON.stringify(devolutions);
            this.goToReturnedObjects();
          } else {
            alert(
              "Erro ao tentar devolver objeto. Por favor, tente novamente."
            );
          }
          console.log(response);
          this.loading = false;
          // this.selectAddress(response.data.addressId, () => {
          //   this.$router.push("/endereco");
          // });
          // this.isLoading = false;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          alert("Erro ao tentar devolver objeto. Por favor, tente novamente.");
        });
    },
    goToReturnedObjects() {
      this.$router.push("/objetos-devolvidos");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Para mim parece um erro de sintaxe.

Comment: @letícia-a Se enviar o html completo, certamente terá melhores respostas.

Comment: Seria bom dar um pouco mais de contexto de onde obteve este trecho. Provavelmente isto não é HTML puro. O HTML tem uma tag chamada object, mas a sintaxe não é esta do seu exemplo. Deve ter alguma tecnologia intermediária processando os dados antes de gerar o HTML "verdadeiro", ou então este trecho veio de algum mecanismo de layout que se assemelha a HTML mas não vai ser usado por um navegador normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como a pergunta é unicamente sobre o `:object` no código, não vou explicar sobre a tag [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) ou algo assim.

Os dois pontos(`:`) antes do atributo é uma diretiva do `Vue.js` para dizer que o valor passado à propriedade é um javascript. Ele é um [açucar sintático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12964/o-que-%C3%A9-syntax-sugar-e-como-ela-funciona) para uma outra diretiva, o [`v-bind`](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Abreviacao-para-v-bind).

Veja um caso de uso:

```js
Vue.component('vue-component', {
  props: ['object'], // Espero pela propriedade "object"
  template: '<div>{{ object }}</div>'
});

new Vue({
    el: '#databinding',
    data: {
        returnedObject : "" // Crio a variável "returnedObject" para o contexto da div com id "databinding"
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="databinding">
    <input type="text" v-model="returnedObject">
    <vue-component :object="returnedObject" /> <!-- Passo a variavel returnedObject como parâmetro para a propriedade object -->
</div>
```